# Showing the stack trace from a running Python application

Tags: python, debugging, stack-trace, traceback

I have this Python application that gets stuck from time to time and I can't find out where.

Is there any way to signal Python interpreter to show you the exact code that's running?

Some kind of on-the-fly stacktrace?

***Related questions:***

- [Print current call stack from a method in Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-from-a-method-in-python-code)
- [Check what a running process is doing: print stack trace of an uninstrumented Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849138/check-what-a-running-process-is-doing-print-stack-trace-of-an-uninstrumented-py)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4163964/1449460

Comment: related https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: This question [debugging - Get stacktrace from stuck python process - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781935/get-stacktrace-from-stuck-python-process) asks for the case where signals doesn't work (although some other answers below addresses that case too)

Answer (score 353, accepted):

I have module I use for situations like this - where a process will be running for a long time but gets stuck sometimes for unknown and irreproducible reasons.  Its a bit hacky, and only works on unix (requires signals):

```
import code, traceback, signal

def debug(sig, frame):
    """Interrupt running process, and provide a python prompt for
    interactive debugging."""
    d={'_frame':frame}         # Allow access to frame object.
    d.update(frame.f_globals)  # Unless shadowed by global
    d.update(frame.f_locals)

    i = code.InteractiveConsole(d)
    message  = "Signal received : entering python shell.\nTraceback:\n"
    message += ''.join(traceback.format_stack(frame))
    i.interact(message)

def listen():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, debug)  # Register handler
```

To use, just call the listen() function at some point when your program starts up (You could even stick it in site.py to have all python programs use it), and let it run.  At any point, send the process a SIGUSR1 signal, using kill, or in python:

```
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
```

This will cause the program to break to a python console at the point it is currently at, showing you the stack trace, and letting you manipulate the variables.  Use control-d (EOF) to continue running (though note that you will probably interrupt any I/O etc at the point you signal, so it isn't fully non-intrusive.

I've another script that does the same thing, except it communicates with the running process through a pipe (to allow for debugging backgrounded processes etc).  Its a bit large to post here, but I've added it as a [python cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576515/).

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. Maybe you could also post that script with pipe support on some Python snippets site?

Comment: I've now posted it at the python cookbook site - link added.

Comment: I needed to add "import readline" to enable history features.

Comment: Great tip! This also works to send the signal, to all processes containing the word "mypythonapp": pkill -SIGUSR1 -f mypythonapp

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in mod_wsgi: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Registration_Of_Signal_Handlers

Comment: Awesome tip indeed. I'm debugging a software that just hangs if I use the standard `pdb` module. I was really running out of options besides `print`.

Comment: This does not work for Windows! There is no `signal.SIGUSR1` available.

Comment: This works on cygwin!  Is there a way to resume the program as is from the shell once you've broken into it like this?

Comment: If the application is stuck, the Python interpreter loop may not be able to run to process the signal.  Use the `faulthandler` module (and its backport found on PyPI) for a C level signal handler that'll print the Python stack without requiring the interpreter loop to be responsive.

Comment: This method seems to not work in multithreaded program. Signal is not catched, tried listening for different signals (USR1, USR2, SIGALRM, SIGTERM), no one works. Possible explanation is http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496735-workaround-for-missed-sigint-in-multithreaded-prog/ , but this provides no mean to get stack trace of program that is stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a shorter version if you need just the stacktrace: 


signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, lambda sig, frame: traceback.print_stack())

Comment: ValueError: signal only works in main thread
do we something for multithreaded app in python

Comment: @BjornTipling How does PDB do this?

Comment: Is there much (or any) overhead to listening for signals like this?

Answer (score 158):

The suggestion to install a signal handler is a good one, and I use it a lot.  For example, [bzr](http://bazaar-vcs.org/) by default installs a SIGQUIT handler that invokes `pdb.set_trace()` to immediately drop you into a [pdb](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-pdb.html) prompt.  (See the [bzrlib.breakin](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ebzr-pqm/bzr/bzr.dev/view/head:/bzrlib/breakin.py) module's source for the exact details.)  With pdb you can not only get the current stack trace (with the `(w)here` command) but also inspect variables, etc.

However, sometimes I need to debug a process that I didn't have the foresight to install the signal handler in.  On linux, you can attach gdb to the process and get a python stack trace with some gdb macros.  Put http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/gdbinit in `~/.gdbinit`, then:

- Attach gdb: `gdb -p` *`PID`*
- Get the python stack trace: `pystack`

It's not totally reliable unfortunately, but it works most of the time.  See also https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Finally, attaching `strace` can often give you a good idea what a process is doing.

Comment: Brilliant!  The pystack command locks up sometimes, but before it does it gives me a complete stack trace of the process, in python code lines, without having needed to do any preparation.

Comment: Minor update: this gdb technique (and updated code) is documented at http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb There's been some development on this front, documented at that URL, and apparently gdb 7 has some Python support.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only really works if you have debug symbols compiled into your python binary - eg: you ran your program with python2-dbg (on Ubuntu, this is in a separate package `python-dbg`). Without those symbols, you don't seem to get much useful info.

Comment: in my case this return `Unable to locate python frame` to each command

Comment: gdb 7+ --with-python support is provided by python-gdb.py. More details here: https://chezsoi.org/lucas/blog/2014/11/07/en-gdb-python-macros/

Answer (score 81):

I am almost always dealing with multiple threads and main thread is generally not doing much, so what is most interesting is to dump all the stacks (which is more like the Java's dump). Here is an implementation based on [this blog](http://bzimmer.ziclix.com/2008/12/17/python-thread-dumps/):

```
import threading, sys, traceback

def dumpstacks(signal, frame):
    id2name = dict([(th.ident, th.name) for th in threading.enumerate()])
    code = []
    for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
        code.append("\n# Thread: %s(%d)" % (id2name.get(threadId,""), threadId))
        for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename, lineno, name))
            if line:
                code.append("  %s" % (line.strip()))
    print("\n".join(code))

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, dumpstacks)
```

Comment: python 3 has a much simpler solution- call [`traceback.print_stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack)

Comment: Which threads does print_stack print from?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24334576 for python 3 to print all threads.

Answer (score 60):

Getting a stack trace of an *unprepared* python program, running in a stock python *without debugging symbols* can be done with [pyrasite](http://pyrasite.readthedocs.org/). Worked like a charm for me in on Ubuntu Trusty:

```
$ sudo pip install pyrasite
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
$ sudo pyrasite 16262 dump_stacks.py # dumps stacks to stdout/stderr of the python program
```

(Hat tip to @Albert, whose answer contained a pointer to this, among other tools.)

Comment: This worked great for me, where `dump_stacks.py` was simply `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()`

Comment: `traceback -l` gives you a list of predefined python scripts you can use, and `dump_stacks.py` is one of them. If you are using your own (for instance to write stack trace to a file) it might be wise to use a different name.

Comment: Important tip: run `apt-get install gdb python-dbg` (or equivalent) before running pyrasite, otherwise it will silently fail. Works like a charm otherwise!

Comment: Last release of pyrasite was [in 2012](https://pypi.org/project/pyrasite/#history)

Comment: (disclaimer: my package) I have a fork pyrasite-ng which fixes various reported bugs.

Comment: Also, pyrasite-shell hung for me.

Answer (score 37):

```
>>> import traceback
>>> def x():
>>>    print traceback.extract_stack()

>>> x()
[('<stdin>', 1, '<module>', None), ('<stdin>', 2, 'x', None)]
```

You can also nicely format the stack trace, see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-traceback.html).

**Edit**: To simulate Java's behavior, as suggested by @Douglas Leeder, add this:

```
import signal
import traceback

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, lambda sig, stack: traceback.print_stack(stack))
```

to the startup code in your application. Then you can print the stack by sending `SIGUSR1` to the running Python process.

Comment: This would only print the backtrace of main thread. I am yet to find a solution for seeing traces for all threads. In fact, python seems to lack an API to retrieve stack from Thread object, though threading.enumerate() gives access to all Thread objects.

Comment: This works great on cygwin.  It only prints three lines of the stack trace though, but that's enough to get a clue

Answer (score 30):

The [**traceback**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module has some nice functions, among them: print_stack:

```
import traceback

traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: To write out the stack trace to a file use:  
`import traceback;  
f = open('/tmp/stack-trace.log', 'w')  
traceback.print_stack(file=f)  
f.close()`

Comment: +1 to @gulgi for his easy to use answer. Some of the other answers looked very complicated for my simple task of getting call-stack trace from a script's function.

Answer (score 27):

You can try the [faulthandler module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/faulthandler.html). Install it using `pip install faulthandler` and add:

```
import faulthandler, signal
faulthandler.register(signal.SIGUSR1)
```

at the beginning of your program. Then send SIGUSR1 to your process (ex: `kill -USR1 42`) to display the Python traceback of all threads to the standard output. [Read the documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/faulthandler.html) for more options (ex: log into a file) and other ways to display the traceback.

The module is now part of Python 3.3. For Python 2, see http://faulthandler.readthedocs.org/

Comment: This one worked for me. My app was crashing and I had no obvious idea why. Thanks to faulthandler I was able to identify line of code that was causing a crash. I was trying to change state of several main UI items by just trying to set them from other thread instead using signals to do that in the main thread.

Answer (score 20):

What really helped me here is [spiv's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application/147114#147114) (which I would vote up and comment on if I had the reputation points) for getting a stack trace out of an *unprepared* Python process. Except it didn't work until I [modified the gdbinit script](http://lists.osafoundation.org/pipermail/chandler-dev/2007-January/007519.html). So:

- download https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/gdbinit and put it in `~/.gdbinit`
- <del>edit it, changing `PyEval_EvalFrame` to `PyEval_EvalFrameEx`</del> [edit: no longer needed; the linked file already has this change as of 2010-01-14]
- Attach gdb: `gdb -p PID`
- Get the python stack trace: `pystack`

Comment: The gdbinit at the mentioned URL already seems to have the patch you suggest.

In my case, when I typed pystack my CPU just hung. Not sure why.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't — I was unclear, sorry, because that line appears in three places. The patch I linked to shows which one I had changed when I saw this work.

Comment: Like @spiv's answer, this requires the program to run under python compiled with debugging symbols. Otherwise you'll just get `No symbol "co" in current context.`

Answer (score 19):

It can be done with excellent [py-spy](https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/). It's *a sampling profiler for Python programs*, so its job is to attach to a Python processes and sample their call stacks. Hence, `py-spy dump --pid $SOME_PID` is all you need to do to dump call stacks of all threads in the `$SOME_PID` process. Typically it needs escalated privileges (to read the target process' memory).

Here's an example of how it looks like for a threaded Python application.

```
$ sudo py-spy dump --pid 31080
Process 31080: python3.7 -m chronologer -e production serve -u www-data -m
Python v3.7.1 (/usr/local/bin/python3.7)

Thread 0x7FEF5E410400 (active): "MainThread"
    _wait (cherrypy/process/wspbus.py:370)
    wait (cherrypy/process/wspbus.py:384)
    block (cherrypy/process/wspbus.py:321)
    start (cherrypy/daemon.py:72)
    serve (chronologer/cli.py:27)
    main (chronologer/cli.py:84)
    <module> (chronologer/__main__.py:5)
    _run_code (runpy.py:85)
    _run_module_as_main (runpy.py:193)
Thread 0x7FEF55636700 (active): "_TimeoutMonitor"
    run (cherrypy/process/plugins.py:518)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:917)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:885)
Thread 0x7FEF54B35700 (active): "HTTPServer Thread-2"
    accept (socket.py:212)
    tick (cherrypy/wsgiserver/__init__.py:2075)
    start (cherrypy/wsgiserver/__init__.py:2021)
    _start_http_thread (cherrypy/process/servers.py:217)
    run (threading.py:865)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:917)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:885)
...
Thread 0x7FEF2BFFF700 (idle): "CP Server Thread-10"
    wait (threading.py:296)
    get (queue.py:170)
    run (cherrypy/wsgiserver/__init__.py:1586)
    _bootstrap_inner (threading.py:917)
    _bootstrap (threading.py:885)
```

Comment: This works, but `hypno` from @kmaork's answer produces a Python traceback, which is a lot more useful for figuring out where the problem is.

Answer (score 14):

*python -dv yourscript.py*

That will make the interpreter to run in debug mode and to give you a trace of what the interpreter is doing.

If you want to interactively debug the code you should run it like this:

*python -m pdb yourscript.py*

That tells the python interpreter to run your script with the module "pdb" which is the python debugger, if you run it like that the interpreter will be executed in interactive mode, much like GDB

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about an already running process.

Comment: what is -dv ? Any link to documentation?

Answer (score 12):

I would add this as a comment to [haridsv's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application/2569696#2569696), but I lack the reputation to do so:

Some of us are still stuck on a version of Python older than 2.6 (required for Thread.ident), so I got the code working in Python 2.5 (though without the thread name being displayed) as such:

```
import traceback
import sys
def dumpstacks(signal, frame):
    code = []
    for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
            code.append("\n# Thread: %d" % (threadId))
        for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename, lineno, name))
            if line:
                code.append("  %s" % (line.strip()))
    print "\n".join(code)

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, dumpstacks)
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [`faulthandler`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#faulthandler) module, new in Python 3.3.  A [`faulthandler` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/) for use in Python 2 is available on PyPI.

Comment: A more recent answer by @haypo covers this in more detail. I'm not sure how this is usually handled on SO, but it feels wrong to have two essentially duplicate answers...

Answer (score 7):

On Solaris, you can use pstack(1) No changes to the python code are necessary. eg.

```
# pstack 16000 | grep : | head
16000: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/lib/pkg.depotd --cfg svc:/application/pkg/serv
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py:282 (_wait) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py:295 (wait) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py:242 (block) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/cherrypy/_init_.py:249 (quickstart) ]
[ /usr/lib/pkg.depotd:890 (<module>) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py:256 (wait) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/Queue.py:177 (get) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/pkg/server/depot.py:2142 (run) ]
[ /usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py:477 (run)
etc.
```

Comment: There appears to be a Debian/Ubuntu programme ``pstack`` that does the same thing

Comment: It seems to only give the backtrace under linux, not the Python traceback with filename and line numbers.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a while for a solution to debug my threads and I found it here thanks to haridsv. I use slightly simplified version employing the traceback.print_stack():

```
import sys, traceback, signal
import threading
import os

def dumpstacks(signal, frame):
  id2name = dict((th.ident, th.name) for th in threading.enumerate())
  for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
    print(id2name[threadId])
    traceback.print_stack(f=stack)

signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, dumpstacks)

os.killpg(os.getpgid(0), signal.SIGQUIT)
```

For my needs I also filter threads by name.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on a Linux system, use the awesomeness of `gdb` with Python debug extensions (can be in `python-dbg` or `python-debuginfo` package). It also helps with multithreaded applications, GUI applications and C modules.

Run your program with:

```
$ gdb -ex r --args python <programname>.py [arguments]
```

This instructs `gdb` to prepare `python <programname>.py <arguments>` and `r`un it.

Now when you program hangs, switch into `gdb` console, press <kbd>Ctr+C</kbd> and execute:

```
(gdb) thread apply all py-list
```

See [example session](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/wiki/HowToDebugDeadlock) and more info [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) and [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [hypno](https://pypi.org/project/hypno/) package, like so:

```
hypno <pid> "import traceback; traceback.print_stack()"
```

This would print a stack trace into the program's stdout.

Alternatively, if you don't want to print anything to stdout, or you don't have access to it (a daemon for example), you could use the [madbg](https://github.com/kmaork/madbg) package, which is a python debugger that allows you to attach to a running python program and debug it in your current terminal. It is similar to `pyrasite` and `pyringe`, but newer, doesn't require gdb, and uses `IPython` for the debugger (which means colors and autocomplete).

To see the stack trace of a running program, you could run:

```
madbg attach <pid>
```

And in the debugger shell, enter:
`bt`

Disclaimer - I wrote both packages

Comment: FTW! `sudo $(which hypno) $(pgrep pytest) "import traceback; traceback.print_stack()"`

(It doesn't work without sudo, despite both processes being owned by the same user.)

Comment: Great to hear! It can work without sudo if you allow ptrace scope on your machine, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19215177/2907819

Answer (score 4):

I hacked together some tool which attaches into a running Python process and injects some code to get a Python shell.

See here: https://github.com/albertz/pydbattach

Comment: Note: it's not obvious how to build this. Thanks for the links you've put in README though: `pyrasite` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

It's worth looking at [Pydb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/pydb/), "an expanded version of the Python debugger loosely based on the gdb command set". It includes signal managers which can take care of starting the debugger when a specified signal is sent.

A 2006 Summer of Code project looked at adding remote-debugging features to pydb in a module called [mpdb](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/pdb/).

Comment: Seems it's gone through two ([1](https://code.google.com/p/pydbgr/)) rewrites ([2](https://github.com/rocky/python2-trepan)) [without adding the attach-by-PID](https://github.com/rocky/python2-trepan/wiki/Tutorial#getting-into-the-debugger) feature I was looking for...

Answer (score 2):

[pyringe](https://github.com/google/pyringe) is a debugger that can interact with running python processes, print stack traces, variables, etc. without any a priori setup.

While I've often used the signal handler solution in the past, it can still often be difficult to reproduce the issue in certain environments.

Comment: Apparently it's incompatible with certain gdb builds (e.g. the one I had installed on ubuntu): https://github.com/google/pyringe/issues/16 , requiring rebuilding manually. Another debugger, `pyrasite`, worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since Austin 3.3, you can use the `-w/--where` option to emit the current stack trace. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905181/1838793

[image]

If you want to peek at a running Python application to see the "live" call stack in a top-like fashon you can use austin-tui (https://github.com/p403n1x87/austin-tui). You can install it from PyPI with e.g.

```
pipx install austin-tui
```

Note that it requires the austin binary to work (https://github.com/p403n1x87/austin), but then you can attach to a running Python process with

```
austin-tui -p <pid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PuDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), a Python debugger with a curses interface to do this. Just add

```
from pudb import set_interrupt_handler; set_interrupt_handler()
```

to your code and use Ctrl-C when you want to break. You can continue with `c` and break again multiple times if you miss it and want to try again.

Comment: When you use the above command in django, don't forget to run a server properly to prevent glitches: "manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading"

Answer (score 1):

I am in the GDB camp with the python extensions. Follow https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb, which means

1. `dnf install gdb python-debuginfo` or `sudo apt-get install gdb python2.7-dbg`
2. `gdb python <pid of running process>`
3. `py-bt`

Also consider `info threads` and `thread apply all py-bt`.

Comment: is it normal to get a response like `Traceback (most recent call first):
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> No frame is currently selected.:
Error occurred in Python command: No frame is currently selected.` when running `py-bt` in `gdb`?

Comment: nevermind. it's because my app was running as `sudo`. i needed to run `gdb pyton <pid>` as sudo, too.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug any function **in console**:

**Create function** where you **use pdb.set_trace()**, then function you want debug.

```py
>>> import pdb
>>> import my_function

>>> def f():
...     pdb.set_trace()
...     my_function()
...
```

Then call created function:

```py
>>> f()
> <stdin>(3)f()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> <stdin>(1)my_function()
(Pdb)
```

Happy debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything similar to [java's response to SIGQUIT](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/stack.html), so you might have to build it in to your application. Maybe you could make a server in another thread that can get a stacktrace on response to a message of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hook into a running python process and get reasonable results.  What I do if processes lock up is hooking strace in and trying to figure out what exactly is happening.

Unfortunately often strace is the observer that "fixes" race conditions so that the output is useless there too.

Comment: Yeah, this is true. It is a shame though thad pdb does not support attaching to a running process...

Comment: This is not true.  See the answer by "spiv" above, which shows how to connect gdb and get a Python stack trace.

Comment: It's not the same -- those gdb macros aren't reliable and don't provide the full power/familiar interface of pdb.  I often wish someone wrote a small app that would use ptrace to inject some Python bytecode into a running Python process and have it execute 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()', maybe also after temporarily redirecting sys.stdin/stdout.

Comment: This is not true anymore, see other answers pointing to pyringe/pyrasite.

Answer (score 0):

use the inspect module.

> > > import inspect
> > >       help(inspect.stack)
> > >       Help on function stack in module inspect:

stack(context=1)
    Return a list of records for the stack above the caller's frame.

I find it very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, pdb will automatically install a signal handler the first time you use c(ont(inue)) in the debugger. Pressing Control-C afterwards will drop you right back in there. In Python 2, here's a one-liner which should work even in relatively old versions (tested in 2.7 but I checked Python source back to 2.4 and it looked okay):

```
import pdb, signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda sig, frame: pdb.Pdb().set_trace(frame))
```

pdb is worth learning if you spend any amount of time debugging Python. The interface is a bit obtuse but should be familiar to anyone who has used similar tools, such as gdb.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to do this with uWSGI, it has [Python Tracebacker](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Tracebacker.html) built-in and it's just matter of enabling it in the configuration (number is attached to the name for each worker):

```
py-tracebacker=/var/run/uwsgi/pytrace
```

Once you have done this, you can print backtrace simply by connecting to the socket:

```
uwsgi --connect-and-read /var/run/uwsgi/pytrace1
```

Answer (score -1):

At the point where the code is run, you can insert this small snippet to see a nicely formatted printed stack trace. It assumes that you have a folder called `logs` at your project's root directory.

```py
# DEBUG: START DEBUG -->
import traceback

with open('logs/stack-trace.log', 'w') as file:
    traceback.print_stack(file=file)
# DEBUG: END DEBUG --!
```