# Setting environment variables, does not work

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

In my terminal, I run

```
echo $X
```

And an empty line is printed because the environment variable `X` is not defined.

Then I run this python code:

```
import os
os.environ['X']='Y'
```

Exited the python console, and checked the value of `X` again

```
echo $X
```

Yet, `X` is still undefined, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are defining the variable in a subshell, so when you exit it you lose the value.

Comment: How can I make the value stay defined after the python shell terminates ?

Comment: As fedorqui said, you're only setting the environment variable within the scope of the Python environment, so it evaporates once you leave the console. [This question may help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist)