# How to set environment variables of parent shell in Python?

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to modify the environment variables on a parent shell from within Python.  What I've attempted so far hasn't worked:

```
~ $ export TESTING=test
~ $ echo $TESTING
test
~ $
~ $
~ $ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:05:38)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['TESTING']
'test'
>>> os.environ['TESTING'] = 'changed'
>>> os.environ['TESTING']
'changed'
>>> quit()
~ $
~ $
~ $ echo $TESTING
test
```

That's all I've been able to come up with.  Can it be done?  How do I set environment variables of parent shell in Python?

Comment: Modifying the environment of a parent process amounts to modifying its memory space, meaning that in general, no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't possible.

Child processes inherit their environments from their parents rather than share them. Therefore any modifications you make to your environment will be reflected *only* in the child (python) process. Practically, you're just overwriting the dictionary the `os` module has created based on your environment of your shell, not the actual environment variables of your shell.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/389683/how-we-can-change-linux-environment-variable-in-python

[Why can't environmental variables set in python persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist)

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is to parse the output of a Python command as shell commands, by using the shell's [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) functionality, which is more often used to evaluate a command in-line of another command. E.g. `` chown `id -u` /somedir ``.

In your case, you need to print shell commands to stdout, which will be evaluated by the shell. Create your Python script and add:

```
testing = 'changed'
print 'export TESTING={testing}'.format(testing=testing)
```

then from your shell:

```
$ `python my_python.sh`
$ echo TESTING
changed
```

Basically, any string will be interpreted by the shell, even `ls`, `rm` etc

Comment: Using backticks to run the expansion result [is buggy for all the reasons given in BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); if you want to treat a string as code for a shell, use `eval` after taking steps (like use of the `shlex.quote()`/`pipes.quote()` functions) to ensure it's safe to process in that way. (The better practice is to pass an *array* out of your shell script and evaluate it as a simple command, but that's a mouthful and notes on doing it right don't fit into a comment, at least, not with a full explanation of why the associated complexity is called for).