# Setting Environment Up with Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

Our environment has a shell script to setup the working area.  `setup.sh` looks like this:

```
 export BASE_DIR=$PWD
 export PATH=$BASE_DIR/bin
 export THIS_VARIABLE=THAT_VALUE
```

The user does the following:

```
 % . setup.sh
```

Some of our users are looking for a `csh` version and that would mean having two setup files.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this work with a common python file.  In [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) Kenneth Reitz suggests using a `setup.py` file in projects, but I'm not sure if Python can set environment variables in the shell as I do above.

Can I replace this shell script with a python script that does the same thing? I don't see how.

(There are other questions that ask this more broadly with many many comments, but this one has a direct question and direct single answer.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't environmental variables set in python persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Python (or generally any process on Unix-like platforms) cannot change its parent's environment.

A common solution is to have your script print the output in a format suitable for the user's shell.  E.g. `ssh-agent` will print out `sh`-compatible global assignments with `-s` or when it sees that it is being invoked from a Bourne-compatible shell; and `csh` syntax if invoked from `csh` or `tcsh` or when explicitly invoked with `-c`.

The usual invocation in `sh`-compatible shells is `$(eval ssh-agent)` -- so the text that the program prints is evaluated by the shell where the user invoked this command.

`eval` is a well-known security risk, so you want to make this code very easy to vet even for people who don't speak much Python (or shell, or anything much else).

If you are, eh *cough,* skeptical of directly supporting Csh users, perhaps you can convince them to run your `sh`-compatible script in a Bourne-compatible shell and then `exec csh` to get their preferred interactive environment.  This also avoids the slippery slope of having an ever-growing pile of little maintenance challenges for supporting Csh, Fish, `rc`, Powershell etc users.