# Error setting / reading environment variables in Flask App | Access env variable in another file

Tags: python, environment-variables

In `__init__.py`, I set the environment variable.

```
import os

# set mkey environment variable
MKEY="xxxx"
os.environ["MKEY"] = MKEY
```

And then I try to read the environment variable in another file - `file1.py`

```
import os
token = os.environ["MKEY"]
```

When I attempt to run the app on localhost, I get an error:

Traceback:

```
token = os.environ["MKEY"]
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MKEY'
```

It looks like the environment variables are not being set properly or are only accessible in the file they are being set. I don't see them here either:

```
for key in os.environ.keys():
    print(key + ": " + os.environ[key])
```

How do I set environment variables that can be accessed across all files in my Flask App? Is there a way to set this in one of the files versus using `export` in the root directory?

Comment: `os.environ` sets the variable for the current session only. Use export for Linux or do it via registry for Windows.

Comment: @user56700 - Is there a way to set this in one of the files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist

Comment: you can use singleton object ie dictionary to store the env variables and use the data from there and can use decorator if there is any update then export the data to env file something like that

Comment: @sahasrara62 mind writing up an answer? i'm not sure if I follow your comment.

Comment: I think it's probably less related to *"being in the same file"* and more related to *"being in the same process"*. Environment variables can not be seen across different processes and WSGI and Nginx are both allowed to use multiple processes (and threads) to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe write a config file, say `config.py` where load all env in object like

```
config = {'db': os.getenv('user', 'user_db')}
```

and

set env there like , you are doing

```
os.environ['mike'] = mike
```

then do

```
config['mike'] = os.environ['mike']
```

and use this `config` object in the other file like

```
from config import config
```

you can write a function to set and update the configs

something like this you can do