# Environment variables in python

Tags: python

I want to set the environment variable for python. I had did all the stuff as to add in system variable under system path or even pythonpath. Even same under user variable but continuously getting error "`PYTHONPATH`' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Can you please describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006722/os-environ-not-setting-environment-variables and other questions.

Comment: Showing the command that causes the error with the exact full text of the error message, and giving the underlying OS could help in getting relevant answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make environment variable changes stick in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/how-do-i-make-environment-variable-changes-stick-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

*By the type of error you are facing* It's clear that you **have problem installing python on windows**. You did installed it, But it's env variables is not set and in your cmd you can not access it and gave you that error.

Follow this instruction [Add Python to the PATH Environmental Variable](https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

Also If you want to work with environment variables in python, you should use `os` module. like this:

to set value:

```
os.environ['myEnv'] = 'something'
```

to get value:
    os.environ.get('myEnv', 'defaultValue')

And remember if you set an environment variable, that variable is accessed only in context of your python code and will not be global for other applications.