# how to use package.json to call a script that sets environment variables and have those variables accessible to other scripts and commands

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a [cookiecutter Flask](https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask) app. I am trying to modify my package.json so that the command `npm start` sets some environment variables with a Python script.

Right now my Python script appears to be behaving correctly, but when the script to start Flask is executed by package.json, the environment variables are not set.

I can start to articulate what is probably causing the problem.  My Python script is probably running in a different process than Flask, and is setting the environment variables in its own process but Flask can't access them.  I need to do some kind of analogue of sourcing my .bashrc.  But I don't know what that analogue is.  Or maybe the problem is something completely different!

Here's a chunk of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors -p",
"start": "npm run set-trusted-vars-no-force && npm run start-servers",
"start-local": "npm run set-local-vars && npm start",
"start-servers": "concurrently -n \"WEBPACK,FLASK\" -c \"bgBlue.bold,bgMagenta.bold\" \"npm run webpack-dev-server\" \"npm run flask-server\"",
"webpack-dev-server": "NODE_ENV=debug webpack-dev-server --port 8081 --hot --inline $PUBLIC",
"flask-server": "flask run",
"lint": "eslint \"assets/js/*.js\"",
"set-trusted-vars": "python ../config/set_env_vars.py --reset T --env trusted --credentials ../config/credentials/secrets.yml --config ../config/config.yml",
"set-trusted-vars-no-force": "python ../config/set_dev_env_vars.py --env trusted --credentials ../config/credentials/secrets.yml --config ../config/config.yml",
"set-local-vars": "python ../config/set_dev_env_vars.py --reset T'",
"set-local-vars-no-force": "python ../config/set_dev_env_vars.py"
```

}

Here's a small relevant chunk of `set_dev_env_vars.py`:

```
def set_config(config_path, config_name):
    with open(config_path) as file:
        configs = yaml.safe_load(file)
        config = configs[config_name]
        for var in config:
            os.environ[var] = str(config[var])
            print(var, os.environ[var])
```

Here's what gets printed:

```
ENV local
FLASK_APP autoapp.py
FLASK_ENV development
SECRET_KEY not-so-secret
FLASK_RUN_PORT 8000
FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
```

Flask eventually complains:

```
[FLASK] Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
[FLASK] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[FLASK] npm ERR! errno 2
[FLASK] npm ERR! cookiecutter_mbam@1.0.0 flask-server: `flask run`
[FLASK] npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

What's the right way to set environment variables so that Flask can find them?

p.s. I know in the absence of other context this might seem like an overengineered solution to setting environment variables, but I'm also dealing with more complicated cases that just aren't visible here.

Comment: " My Python script is probably running in a different process than Flask,..." Yes that is the core issue. The usual solution is for the python process to write the env vars to stdout. Then the calling process captures that output and uses it to set the vars in its address space. I don't know Flask so I can't tell you how to arrange for it to do that. What makes you think `set-trusted-vars` is special and causes your python program to run? Google says that appears in exactly two documents; one of which is this question. Have you read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/?

Comment: set-trusted-vars was my addition to `scripts`.  Actually looking at it now it's definitely never running, because I forgot to update the name of the Python script, but what is running is `set-trusted-vars-no-force`; `npm start` is causing it to run, and it's what's calling `set_dev_env_vars.py`. Yes, I've read the configuration docs from Flask.  The Flask docs aren't that relevant to this question.  Internally, the Flask app is going to read environment variables.  My question is really about setting environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

> My Python script is probably running in a different process than Flask, and is setting the environment variables in its own process but Flask can't access them.

Setting environment variables with `os.environ['FOO']='bar'` sets them for the duration of the process or its children [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006803/2052575). 
[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365394/set-environment-variable-in-python-script) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/how-do-i-make-environment-variable-changes-stick-in-python) discourage trying to make Python set them globally, among some hacky solutions.

Not only this, but if `set_dev_env_vars.py` did set the environment variables globally, this ties the frontend to the same machine as the Flask server.  It is standard procedure to separate these two. I'm curious if you have a reason for starting the backend server from the frontend?  Is this the behaviour of flask-cookiecutter or something you've implemented yourself (or are stuck with?)

Presumably `config.yml` contains the frontend config also.  Perhaps you should separate the flask related configuration values from there and write them to a `.env` file and load them into your Flask application with [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). You could even make the frontend load its config with [`dot-env` (javascript)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Having this separation would then allow you to deploy the frontend separately from the backend, by simply making sure the required `.env` file is available to the respective server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I did inherit this scheme from cookiecutter, but I'm not stuck with anything if I can make a good case for getting rid of it, and I wasn't considering that as a possibility before.  If I make a Python script responsible for orchestration I can make the process that sets the environment variables the parent.  Or maybe I'll just write to .env -- I was interested in finding another way so that a set of more standard variables could be set in the actual environment and then an individual developer could use the .env for transient or idiosyncratic overrides.

Comment: The other reason I wanted to avoid using .env is that some of the environment variables are going to be credentials to other applications and I thought it would be safer if they were never written to a file.

Comment: Even if I kept `npm start` as the means of starting my application, I could still just change the scripts it invokes so that either `flask run` gets a parent that sets environment variables (whether because that parent has accepted them to stdin or has determined them itself.