# Gitlab-CI environment variable from Python script to pipeline

Tags: python, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

How I can get the gitlab-ci environment variable `VERSION` value from the python script - `get_version.py` for a gitlab-runners which will work on both OS windows and linux?
I need some universal solution so that it works on both OS.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
stages:
  - versioning

variables:
  VERSION: ""

versioning:
  stage: versioning
  script:
  - echo "[versioning] ..."
  - python ./ci-cd_scripts/get_version.py
  - echo $VERSION
```

Here is my `./ci-cd_scripts/get_version.py` :

```
import os

refName = os.environ.get("CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME")
piplineID = os.environ.get("CI_PIPELINE_ID")
relVersion = refName + ".0." + piplineID

version = relVersion.replace("rel.", "")
print("current version is", version)
```

[python output in pipeline log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2XNc.jpg)

Comment: Please paste your code and log in your answer instead of having images.

Answer (score 5):

what I found that works is to save it to a temp file.

```
import os

refName = os.environ.get("CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME")
piplineID = os.environ.get("CI_PIPELINE_ID")
relVersion = refName + ".0." + piplineID

version = relVersion.replace("rel.", "")
print("current version is", version)
with open('.env', 'w') as writer:
     writer.write(f'export VERSION="{version}"')
```

and then in the pipeline you just export the variable using the .env file

```
script:
  - ./ci-cd_scripts/get_version.py
  - source .env
  - echo $VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not normally possible

You can set and modify environment variables using `os.environ` inside Python scripts but as the scripts is finished, everything goes back to the previous value.

It would be helpful to read these posts on StackOverflow :

[Why can't environmental variables set in python persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/) 
[How do I make environment variable changes stick in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/) 
[Environment Variables in Python on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235435/)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `get_version.py` python script to have :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("export VERSION='{}'".format(value))
```

and then in your pipeline :

```
script:
  - eval `python ./ci-cd_scripts/get_version.py`
  - echo $VERSION
```

Comment: But this solution will not work on Windows runner, because "eval" command not supported in CMD or Powershell. I need a universal solution so that it works for runners on both OS Windows and Linux