# Python REPL for a running process

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I am currently developing a simple application in python that connects to a server. At the moment, it's single-threaded (as multithreading is not currently required).

However I would like - for debugging, maintenance and such to also be able to have a REPL via stdin.

How do I go about that, if possible? Will I need to keep anything in mind? Will I have to make a separate thread for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application) question could help. You can modify it a bit to create a customized REPL.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to go non-blocking or use a thread.

I would personally use Twisted for concurrency, which also offers a REPL-protocol which is easy to integrate.

Comment: +1: twisted also offers the manhole - a service where you can SSH to your application and get a REPL to interact with it while it is running!

Comment: I'm going to give this a go. Sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [rfoo](https://github.com/aaiyer/rfoo). From the README:

> rconsole - included with rfoo package is a remote Python console with
>   auto completion, which can be used to inspect and modify namespace of a
>   running script.
>
> To activate in a script do:

```
from rfoo.utils import rconsole
rconsole.spawn_server()
```

> To attach from a shell do:

```
$ rconsole
```

> SECURITY NOTE:
>   The rconsole listener started with spawn_server() will accept any local 
>   connection and may therefore be insecure to use in shared hosting
>   or similar environments!