# In gevent, how can I dump stack traces of all running greenlets?

Tags: python, gevent

For debugging purposes, I would like to iterate over all greenlets and obtain their trace traces -- how can I do that with gevent?

Basically, I would like to do the gevent equivalent of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032813/dump-stacktraces-of-all-active-threads).

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `gc` module to iterate through all the objects on the heap and search for greenlets. Greenlets store the stack traces as an attribute `gr_frame`.

```
import gc
import traceback
from greenlet import greenlet

for ob in gc.get_objects():
    if not isinstance(ob, greenlet):
        continue
    if not ob:
        continue
    log.error(''.join(traceback.format_stack(ob.gr_frame)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Gevent's built-in "print_run_info" function will print the stacks of all greenlets, including the stacks of where they were spawned from:

```
import gevent
gevent.util.print_run_info()
```

Documentation: http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.util.html#gevent.util.print_run_info

Comment: The question specifically says " I would like to do the gevent equivalent of this."