# In a gevent application, how can I kill all greenlets that have been started?

Tags: python, gevent

I have a gevent application that spawns multiple greenlets across multiple modules. I want to be able to gracefully shutdown the application (either internally or by catching `SIGTERM`, for instance), allowing greenlets to terminate nicely by catching `GreenletExit` and executing `finally:` clauses.

If I had the a of all running greenlets, I could do `gevent.killall(list_of_greenlets)`, but maintaining such a list is rather a hassle; besides, gevent must be keeping this very list in some form or another.

So, can I kill all greenlets that have been started without maintaining a list of them?

(I'm using gevent 1.0.0 on python 2.7 on raspbian)

Comment: We need more details of your implementation of greenlets. Are you using a pool, f.e.? Maybe ```gevent.shutdown()``` works for you?

Comment: Most modules are going to use simply `gevent.spawn()`, but some might be using a pool or whatever they like. Also, there is no `gevent.shutdown()` in 1.0.0, and even if there were, it cannot be run from a non-main greenlet, and signal handler is more than likely to end up in a different one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510648/in-gevent-how-can-i-dump-stack-traces-of-all-running-greenlets), it's possible "to iterate through all the objects on the heap and search for greenlets." So, I imagine this ought to work:

```
import gc
import gevent
from greenlet import greenlet    
gevent.killall([obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, greenlet)])
```

Answer (score 3):

This didn't quite work for the versions of gevent (1.2.2) and greenlet (0.4.13) I was using but the following does:

```
import gc
import gevent
gevent.killall(
    [obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, gevent.Greenlet)]
)
```