# how to get python eventlet stack throuth gdb

Tags: python, gdb, coroutine, eventlet

I have a python program. It has many eventlet coroutine.
It seems that the program have dead lock someday. I have dumped its memory.
I want to find reason. **The question is how to get eventlet coroutine stack using gdb.**

Additional Information:

1. I know how to get all thread stack through gdb. But it comes to eventlet coroutine，it became difficult. Because I have not enough info about python interpreter.
2. I also know how to get all eventlet coroutine stack in a python program by iterating all object. But it is useless to the situation we should check all object through gdb.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way as with regular threads.

Here are some hints to help you, though:

- Multiple useful lessons on debugging Python with GDB http://grapsus.net/blog/post/Low-level-Python-debugging-with-GDB
- Use `eventlet.backdoor` to have emergency in-process interpreter for debugging http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/backdoor.html
- Search `gc.get_objects()` for instances of `greenlet`, print stack of `x.gr_frame` [In gevent, how can I dump stack traces of all running greenlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510648/in-gevent-how-can-i-dump-stack-traces-of-all-running-greenlets)
- Setup signal handler (e.g. USR1) that iterates all greenthreads and prints their stack to stderr