# What's the modern way to solve Plone deadlock issues?

Tags: plone, deadlock, multilingual

I currently have a Plone 4.3.8 site where editing a portlet causes a deadlock.

I'm trying to find tools to fix this, but most deadlock tools don't work & I'm not getting good information (IMO) from those that at least run.

I've tried:

- z3c.deadlockdebugger => can't get to a stacktrace
- ZopeHealthWatcher => can't see the results on command line (or webpage)
- [Products.LongRequestLogger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.LongRequestLogger) => perhaps the best so far, gives me some log output - but it's stack traces focus on Diazo code, but the problem still occurs when Diazo isn't in scope (running against 127.0.0.1)
- gdb attach  - just landed me in C code
- [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/docs/) => it can't attach to running processes  in the same way that gdb can (only to processes started with the intention of attachment by winpdb)
- [Products.signalstack](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.signalstack) (OR Products.signalstacklogger)  => USR1 signal just shuts down a zope process!

Note: z3c.deadlockdebugger (and things that depend on it) needs checked out [source code](https://github.com/malthe/z3c.deadlockdebugger) to drop the  threadframe dependency.

My situation seems to be linked to product upgrades - probably one or both of either plone.app.contenttypes or plone.app.multilingual, an empty site doesn't have this issue, but I obviously I need my site data!

What should I do to progress this?

EDIT:

I believe Maurits answer to be the most correct one, but it didn't work in my case.  What I ended up doing was using pdb to track down the point at which the code was hanging (in plone.app.debugtoolbar as it happens)

Comment: About the threadframe dependency: it's longly deprecated but you can also choose to include it in your buildout adding it to the `eggs` section. As it's not published on pypi you must also add an additional `find-links` (`https://majid.info/python/threadframe/`) and the `allow-hosts`.

Comment: @keul majid's site [article on threadframe](https://majid.info/blog/threadframe-multithreaded-stack-frame-extraction-for-python/) says: "Python 2.5 and later include a function sys._current_frames()" so I'm taking that advice

Comment: yes, it's true, but if you don't want to modify source code you can still use threadframe (although deprecated and useless).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that using the `USR1` signal shuts down Zope when using Products.signalstack. But no special packages should be necessary, so I wonder if adding signalstack has this side effect of shutting down Zope.

At least for me, a few weeks ago, this worked fine on a Plone 4.3.something site:

```
kill -USR1 $(cat var/zeoclient.pid)
```

Comment: Ok - I've removed signalstack (but kept Products.LongRequestLogger) - and that does work at giving a stacktrace before I try to edit the portlet, but sadly it *doesn't* work afterwards.  I'm confused as to why? I caught this in development, so I'm debugging a standalone instance rather than a ZEO client - that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: Indeed, `Products.singalstack` was [integrated into Zope 2.12.5](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/16796274463f21327e1b7bb3831b39eb671460af) back in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Although the @maurits answer is right (and the simplest ones) sometimes I had issues seeing the traceback resulting from the `kill` command: sometimes is found on the event log, sometimes on the shell.

I prefer the integration of the buildout with [haufe.requestmonitoring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haufe.requestmonitoring/), configuring also the [monitor long running requests feature](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haufe.requestmonitoring/#monitoring-long-running-requests).
You will see the deadlocked traceback in your event log and also you activate a tool for monitoring low performance on your Plone.

Comment: thanks - but this didn't work for me either - I can't see a traceback in either location

Comment: If you don't see the traceback you probably not configured the long running request features as described in the link I gave you

Comment: I did do this, but then @maurits method didn't produce a stack trace for me either.  Not to worry - pdb got me there in the end. Thanks!