# Plone site update runs ages now

Tags: database, plone, upgrade

I update a Plone instance from 4.0.3 to 4.3.11 and now the site update runs for about 16 hours. Shure, the webserver timouted after an hour or so, but the process is still running. Strace says:

```
select(12, [4 11], [], [4 11], {25, 609847}) = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x1d01d30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x1d01d30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x1d01d30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x1d01d30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
select(12, [4 11], [], [4 11], {30, 0}
```

while this line

```
select(12, [4 11], [], [4 11], {30, 0}
```

repeats very often and sometimes this occours:

```
futex(0x1d01d30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

`iostat` is telling me that the Disk (new SSD) is utilized 10% max, but mostly it is idling around. It is also the system-disk, so I don't exclusively see plones Disk IO.

The Database for the site contains about 60.0000 Objects, mostly of the same type. They are very small objects with no fancy extra.

The machine has 16GB memory and 8 Cores. While only one core is performing the actual plone-upgrade (why?)

Does it really take this long to Upgrade the ZEO DB with 60.000 objects? How can I know, that he is really doing something? (strace is not very telling here).

Comment: That update will do at least one, possibly several, re-indexing steps. Indexing a file might involve spinning up external tools to convert them to text. As alepisa suggests, look at the instance logs, indexing steps leave progress markers there.

Answer (score 1):

> The machine has 16GB memory and 8 Cores. While only one core is performing the actual plone-upgrade (why?)

Because only one thread (so one CPU) is running the upgrade.

> Does it really take this long to Upgrade the ZEO DB with 60.000 objects?

It is not normal. Maybe you have some custom code which is making strange things. Are you connecting to other services (solr, other databases, ...)? Are you generating document previews? How big is your Data.fs and how many blobs do you have?

> How can I know, that he is really doing something?

The first step for debugging it, is to know what is happening. Try to install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.LongRequestLogger (or similar addons).

This is going to point out the point where you are stuck in.

If you have the instance running in foreground you can also have a traceback by sending the USR1 signal. See:

- [What's the modern way to solve Plone deadlock issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629957/whats-the-modern-way-to-solve-plone-deadlock-issues)

for a more complete insight.

> webserver timeouted after an hour or so

This also sounds strange. If the webserver is apache or nginx, the time out should be in the minute range.

If you call directly the instance port, you should not have any timeout at all.

I suggest you to do so.

Also the instance logs (usually under `$BUILDOUT_DIRECTORY/var/log/`) should suggest you about the status of your upgrades.

Comment: Ohh yeah. I realized now, that for every update step, my plone does a catalogUpdate. I'll see, if I can skip that. But it is working...Maybe I should re-title my question.

Comment: This is normal, but on 60k objects it should not take that much... Maybe you have some custom indexes or metadata?

Comment: I removed the catalog update from the setup of a custom addon and reached the point that I asked this question in about 20 minutes. I expect this to be done after an hour or so.