# Print current call stack from a method in code

Tags: python, debugging, stack-trace

In Python, how can I print the current call stack from within a method (for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 498, accepted):

Here's an example of getting the stack via the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module, and printing it:

```
import traceback

def f():
    g()

def g():
    for line in traceback.format_stack():
        print(line.strip())

f()

# Prints:
# File "so-stack.py", line 10, in <module>
#     f()
# File "so-stack.py", line 4, in f
#     g()
# File "so-stack.py", line 7, in g
#     for line in traceback.format_stack():
```

If you really only want to print the stack to stderr, you can use:

```
traceback.print_stack()
```

Or to print to stdout (useful if want to keep redirected output together), use:

```
traceback.print_stack(file=sys.stdout)
```

But getting it via `traceback.format_stack()` lets you do whatever you like with it.

Comment: How to do the same for all other threads *(I’m talking about threads I don’t control)* ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but you call f which it's only purpose is here is to call g and does nothing else. Why

Comment: @Chris: It's just an example.  It has multiple functions to make it clear that format_stack() prints all the calls on the stack.

Comment: If you want to get some more verbose output (including vars etc), see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308607/python-assert-improved-introspection-of-failure), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088160/traceback-print-stack-using-ipythons-ultratb).

Comment: @user2284570: You can use `sys._current_frames()`. E.g. [py_better_exchook `dump_all_thread_tracebacks`](https://github.com/albertz/py_better_exchook/) does that (disclaimer: I wrote that).

Comment: Is there any concern of having production code relying on traceback.format_stack()?

Comment: Why do we need f()?
Can't we just call g()?

Answer (score 154):

```
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: Actually, I like `traceback.print_exc()` which gives you almost the same thing you would have gotten without the `except` statement (and is also less coding than the accepted answer).

Comment: `traceback.print_exc()` prints the stack trace for any exception that you might be handling - but this does not solve the original question, which is how to print the _current_ stack ("where you are now" as opposed to "where your code was when the last exception went off, if any".)

Comment: It may be useful to limit the trace to a number of entries, e.g.:  traceback.print_stack(limit=4)

Answer (score 105):

for those who need to print the call stack while using pdb, just do

```
(Pdb) where
```

Answer (score 78):

`inspect.stack()` returns the current stack rather than the exception traceback:

```
import inspect
print inspect.stack()
```

See https://gist.github.com/FredLoney/5454553 for a log_stack utility function.

Comment: Should have much more votes, `inspect` *feels* way better to use.

Answer (score 22):

If you use python debugger, not only interactive probing of variables but you can get the call stack with the "where" command or "w".

So at the top of your program

```
import pdb
```

Then in the code where you want to see what is happening

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

and you get dropped into a prompt

Comment: I've been programming in Python for over a decade. There are *so* many times I could have used this! I can't believe I'm just now finding out about it.

Comment: How does this relate to `where`?

Comment: To answer the "where" part of the question: After you get the pdb prompt `(pdb) ` just type `where` and it will print the stack trace to the terminal.

Comment: Python 3.7 and above have a builtin function `breakpoint()` which obviates the need to import pdb.

Comment: A note for anyone who tries this out in a jupyter notebook: enter exit() into the prompt to get the cell to finish executing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a variation of @RichieHindle's excellent answer which implements a decorator that can be selectively applied to functions as desired. Works with Python 2.7.14 and 3.6.4.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import functools
import traceback
import sys

INDENT = 4*' '

def stacktrace(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwds):
        # Get all but last line returned by traceback.format_stack()
        # which is the line below.
        callstack = '\n'.join([INDENT+line.strip() for line in traceback.format_stack()][:-1])
        print('{}() called:'.format(func.__name__))
        print(callstack)
        return func(*args, **kwds)

    return wrapped

@stacktrace
def test_func():
    return 42

print(test_func())
```

Output from sample:

```
test_func() called:
    File "stacktrace_decorator.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(test_func())
42
```

Comment: Wrote my own decorator version before I saw this. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Install **Inspect-it**

```
pip3 install inspect-it --user
```

**Code**

```
import inspect;print(*['{:40}| {}:{}\n'.format(x.function, x.filename, x.lineno) for x in inspect.stack()])
```

**you can Make a snippet of this line**

it will show you a list of the **function call stack** with a filename and line number

*list from start to where you put this line*

Answer (score 0):

Use `walk_stack` method to return to the history stored in the current stack (`None`):

```py
import traceback
for trace, _ in traceback.walk_stack(None):
    print(trace)
    print(trace.f_locals)
```