# traceback.print_stack() using IPython's ultratb

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, stack-trace, traceback

For debugging/logging purposes, I would like to write the full stack to a file (such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156023/974555)).  I can do this using [`traceback.format_stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_stack).  However, I would like it to look like the more verbose tracebacks that `IPython` outputs, for example, formatting with [`IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB`](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.ultratb.html#IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB).

It appears the classes and methods in `IPython.core.ultratb` require information on exceptions, as they are designed for tracebacks.  But I have no exception: I just want to display the stack in a verbose way.

How can I use the output methods of `IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB` to format the stack such as reported by [`traceback.extract_stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack) or [`inspect.stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack)?

Comment: try something like ```ltratb.VerboseTB()(etb=traceback.extract_stack())```

Comment: @shhdup that gives `AttributeError: 'StackSummary' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'` (in `inspect.getinnerframes`) *and* `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` (in `ultratb.VerboseTB.format_records`).  I'm not sure why I get two exceptions (with tracebacks) for a single expression, but I do.

Comment: See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308607/python-assert-improved-introspection-of-failure). E.g. the [py_better_exchook library](https://github.com/albertz/py_better_exchook/) can do that, via its `print_tb` (disclaimer: I wrote that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import IPython.core.ultratb
import sys

try:
    1/0
except Exception as exc:
    tb = IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB()
    print(tb.text(*sys.exc_info()))

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-8-725405cc4e58> in <module>()
#       1 try:
# ----> 2     1/0
#       3 except Exception as exc:
#       4     tb = IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB()
#       5     print(tb.text(*sys.exc_info()))
# 
# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Note that this will give you the stack of the exception only, not the full stack.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is specified that a full traceback is desired regardless of exception. Besides, even if you add code inside the try block you will only get a traceback for the divide by zero exception.