# printing logging.exception in jupyter notebook with coloring instead of black and white

Tags: python, exception, logging

```py
a = []
import logging 
try: 
    a[1]
except Exception as e: 
    logging.exception(e)
```

This generates a black and white traceback of the exception.
I ran from a notebook, is there a way to output this with the usual color scheme seen in jupyter notebook tracebacks?

Answer (score 0):

When run in Jupyter, this will print what you should be seeing now, **followed by the colored, full traceback below that**:

```py
# based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html and
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410847/8508004 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702847/8508004 and bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779794/8508004 (Although I found
# that didn't actually need `exc_info=True` in `logging.exception(e, exc_info=True)`?) , but still pertinent because states "with tracebacks as well, because log.exception produces logs of only one level - ERROR."
# (Other things had also said logging goes to stderr channel -- related info at https://stackoverflow.com/q/58971197/8508004 and in [Creating Beautiful Tracebacks with Python's Exception Hooks](https://martinheinz.dev/blog/66))
a = []
import sys
import logging 
import IPython.core.ultratb  #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410847/8508004
tb = IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB() #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410847/8508004

try: 
    a[1]
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
    print(tb.text(*sys.exc_info()))
```

I've tested this in vanilla JupyterLab and current classic notebook interface (soon to be called more along the line of the 'document-oriented interface' with V7 of the Jupyter Notbeook).

Key additions are importing `sys` so can use `sys.exc_info()` and bringing in `ultratb` that apparently is used to handle tracebacks in Jupyter and then sending the traceback to `IPython.core.ultratb.VerboseTB()`.

Solution based mainly on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36088160/8508004).  I put a lot of the associated resources in the comments at the top of the code block.