# How to perform assert introspection in Python

Tags: python, assert, pytest

I'm looking into how to perform assert introspection in Python, in the same way [that `py.test` does](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#asserting-with-the-assert-statement). For example...

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> assert a == b
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError   # <--- I want more information here, eg 'AssertionError: 1 != 2'
```

I see that the `py.code` library [has some functionality around this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/py/blob/master/py/_code/assertion.py) and I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308607/python-assert-improved-introspection-of-failure), noting that `sys.excepthook` allows you to plug in whatever behavior you want to exceptions, but it's not clear to me how to put it all together.

Comment: Why not use `pytest` itself?

Comment: @pylang I've no problem with re-using the parts of py.test that allow this to happen, but I can't just use py.test itself. For the purposes of my question I say you should assume eg. that I'm not actually running tests in this context.

Comment: @pylang Is it actually possible to use pytest's assert in a general context? I assume OP wants to use the functionality in a stand-alone program / library, e.g., for validation purposes.

Comment: I think I see now.  Yes, I don't believe pytes has an interactive mode (at least not in jupyter notebooks).  Traditionally, I have used `nose` because of this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is straightforward to reproduce pytest's assert introspection in a standalone context. The docs contain a few more [details](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.1/assert.html#assert-details) on how it works:

> pytest rewrites test modules on import. It does this by using an import hook to write a new pyc files. Most of the time this works transparently. However, if you are messing with import yourself, the import hook may interfere. If this is the case, simply use --assert=reinterp or --assert=plain. Additionally, rewriting will fail silently if it cannot write new pycs, i.e. in a read-only filesystem or a zipfile.

It looks like it would require quite some hacks to make that work in arbitrary modules, so you're probably better off to use a solution suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to show a detailed error message

```
def assertion(a,b):
    try:
        assert a==b
    except AssertionError as e:
        e.args += ('some other', 'information',)
        raise

a=1
b=2
assertion(a,b)
```

This code will give this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tp.py", line 11, in <module>
    assertion(a,b)
  File "tp.py", line 4, in assertion
    assert a==b
AssertionError: ('some other', 'information')
```

Comment: @Tom . Does this help ?

Comment: Not especially, no, but appreciated anyway. This answer adds in other additional information to the exception, but what I'm interested in is the state of the comparison itself. In this case that means including the values of a and b and determining that the issue was that they were not equal. (But a general purpose method that can also worth with other operators)