# Log call stack in Python

Tags: python-2.7, stack-trace, introspection, pdb

I'm debugging huge web app which was not written by me. That is why i need a way to print every stack call somewhere (stdout or file).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-in-python) discussion did not help me. I was thinking about pdb but it requires interaction while i'm looking for automated solution. I have only one function call at the beginning of execution of my app and want to see all other calls it makes.

The behaviour should be somewhat similar to Unix *tee* command. Python interpreter should execute code and at the same time it should log all function calls from different modules.

Any suggestions?

Edited:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import openerp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    openerp.cli.main()
```

So from this point i'd like to log all function calls that main() does.

Comment: Were none of the answers helpful? What about http://stackoverflow.com/a/16200714/3001761?

Comment: print inspect.stack() does not provide any information in my case since i have imported function call in my entry point to the program. So, answering your question no they were not.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're running and want to log? It might help others identify appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the python trace module you can debug each funcion or line where that interpreter executes.

The trace moudule can be called from the cli without modifying the program:

```
  #print each executed line:
  python -m trace --count -C . -t MypyFile.py
  #print only called functions:
  python -m trace --listfuncs MypyFile.py
```

With -t each line is traced and with -l each function called.

More info : https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html