# Debug where method returns None

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a big legacy Python method which contains roughly twenty `return` statements.

The method should not return `None` but it does so. It is repeatable in a simple test case.

Up to now I used a debugger and stepped through the code line by line to find the matching return statement.

But is there an easier way?

Is there a way to raise an Exception as soon as the method returns None?

and Of course I need to see the line containing the return statement.

Example:

```
def big_method(arg1, some_var):
    #.... many returns
    if arg1:
        return some_var # <------
    #... many returns


assert not big_method(True, None) is None
```

Above is a simple code snippet. The result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/modwork_vums_d/src/manyreturns.py", line 8, in <module>
    assert not big_method(True, None) is None
AssertionError
```

Above traceback does not help very much, since I want to see the line **inside** `big_method()`. In the example above I want to see which I marked with `<------`.

I use PyCharm, but a pure python or other solution is welcome.

Just for the records. There is a follow-up question which tries to enable this feature in PyCharm: [PyCharm: Debugging: r(eturn) Continue execution until the current function returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887099/pycharm-debugging-return-continue-execution-until-the-current-function-retur)

Comment: There is a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156048/5588279.

Comment: I wonder this would be possible, the frame to execute big_method has already get reclaimed.

Comment: maybe you could leverage on interpreter's trace function, to record the execution path of the function being called, then print out when outer assertion failed.

Comment: but as you are using a debugger, I guess it should have a functionality like "run until the current function returns", which will stop at the line you need.

Comment: @georgexsh I use PyCharm, but I don't know all features of it. I only now a way to run until big_method() finished. But then the debug-cursor is outside big_method() and I don't see where the interpreter was before. Maybe I am blind, I see the return value, but I don't see which return statement was used.

Comment: `pdb` has this feature, could you give it a try?

Comment: @georgexsh pdb can do it? Nice. Can you please give me a matching term, I would like to read the docs.

Comment: @guettli [link of pdb `r` command doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-return)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

pdb has a `r(eturn)` command for this need:

> r(eturn)
>   Continue execution until the current function returns.

example:

```
> /Users/georgexsh/wasteland/tmp/app.py(6)<module>()
-> assert not big_method(True, None) is None
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/georgexsh/wasteland/tmp/app.py(1)big_method()
-> def big_method(arg1, some_var):
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/georgexsh/wasteland/tmp/app.py(3)big_method()->None
-> return some_var
```

see more detail in [pdb doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-return).