# Python nested vs chained function calls in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am wondering about the output

```
sys: maxRecursionDepth = 10
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f1, 
 >>> maxRecursionDepth =  2
# -----------------------------
sys: maxRecursionDepth = 10
f1, f1, f1, f1, f1, f1, 
 >>> maxRecursionDepth =  6
```

of code provided below.

What I am wondering about is: **What causes that chaining of function calls compared to nesting of function calls has different impact on the by the counter counted calls to the topmost function starting the recursion?** In other words, how does it come that nested calls don't reduce the depth of recursion like the chained calls do? All of the nested functions wait for their parameter being evaluated, so they should take space on the stack, but it seems that they don't.

```
from sys import getrecursionlimit, setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10)
print(f'sys: maxRecursionDepth = {getrecursionlimit()}')
cnt = 0
def f1():
    global cnt
    print('f1', end=', ')
    cnt += 1
    f2()
def f2():
    print('f2', end=', ')
    f3()
def f3():
    print('f3', end=', ')
    f4()
def f4():
    print('f4', end=', ')
    f5()
def f5():
    print('f5', end=', ')
    f1()
# ---
try:
    f1()
except RecursionError:
    print(f'\n >>> maxRecursionDepth =  {cnt}') # 200
    # RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

print('# -----------------------------')

#"""
from sys import getrecursionlimit, setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10)
print(f'sys: maxRecursionDepth = {getrecursionlimit()}')
cnt = 0
def f1():
    global cnt
    print('f1', end=', ')
    cnt += 1
    f2(f3(f4(f5(f1()))))
def f2(f):
    print('f2', end=', ')
    f(f3)
def f3(f):
    print('f3', end=', ')
    f(f4)
def f4(f):
    print('f4', end=', ')
    f5()
def f5(f):
    print('f5', end=', ')
    f1()
# ---
try:
    f1()
except RecursionError:
    print(f'\n >>> maxRecursionDepth =  {cnt}') # 996
    # RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
f2(f3(f4(f5(f1()))))
```

it's roughly equivalent to

```
temp1 = f1()
temp2 = f5(temp1)
temp3 = f4(temp2)
temp4 = f3(temp3)
f2(temp4)
```

Each of the argument function calls is completed before calling the next one in the chain, so they don't add to the recursion depth.

You only add to the recursion depth when the body of a function calls another function. So you get recursion when `f1()` calls `f2()`, `f2()` calls `f3()`, ... and `f5()` calls `f1()`. Since this is infinite recursion, the initial `f1()` call never completes, so none of the chained calls happen, either.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the explanation. `temp2 = f5(temp1)` should result in an attempt to run f5 with the parameter temp1. But f5 is not run so it can't be completed. **What do you exactly mean with *function call is completed*?"" In my eyes none of the function calls is 'completed' waiting in the chain for execution ... Hmmm ... I will check it out in case of going out of recursion without bumping into RecursionError.

Comment: It's completed when the function returns. If the function raises an exception, it doesn't complete, and none of the rest of the calls will happen.

Comment: But the point is that these chained calls don't add to the recursion depth. You only get extra depth when the function calls another function itself.

Comment: > In `f2(f3(f4(f5(f1()))))` **Python will evaluate the innermost expression first**. That's the recursive call f1(). And since f1 calls f1 again, f2 and etc ... are never actually called, so they could not complete. If there is no RecursionError after f1 exits regularly all of the nested f2,f3,f4,f5 are executed the number of times f1 was run. But the calls to them seem to be stacked elsewhere not on the recursion stack. **Where???**

Comment: I'm just answering the question of why chained calls are different. What happens inside `f1()` is irrelevant to this.

Comment: I've added more to the answer.

Comment: **You only add to the recursion depth when the body of a function calls another function.** - explains best the difference between the chained and nested case, but leaves the question open *where are all these calls to the postponed other functions stored?* if the are not stored on the stack reducing the recursion depth???

Comment: They're not stored anywhere. The compiler turns the chained calls into something very similar to what I wrote. Use the disassembler to see it.

Comment: You can see this in tdelaney's answer. They're sequential, not stacked.

Comment: Do I understand it right if I assume that the compiler creates further new code to execute with each recursion loop in such nested case? So the size of code to execute will eventually grow and cause an memory overflow if the recursion depth is sufficiently high? Am I on the right track or on a wrong one?

Comment: No, there's no new code for each recursion depth. There's just one copy of each function in memory. Local variables are stored on the stack, not functions.

Comment: How is the recursion **rewinded** then? Are there some data/variables saved with each next loop to induce later calls to the functions? The short piece of disassembly does not explain it to me. At least the number of run recursion loops must be saved somehow to run the rewinding the same number of times f1 was run.

Comment: The stack also contains the call/return state.

Comment: > *They're (the recursion loopings) not stored anywhere. The compiler turns the chained calls into something very similar to what I wrote. Use the disassembler to see it.*. Sorry, I am not very familiar with the disassembler. Just want to understand how the recursion will be rewinded if not crashed by an RecursionError.

Comment: The stack contains the location to return to. So when you return, it removes the local variables and return location from the stack, and then resumes execution at the return location.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, `f2(f3(f4(f5(f1()))))`, python will evaluate the innermost expression first. That's the recursive call `f1()`. And since `f1` calls `f1` again, `f2` and etc... are never called. Notice that only "f1" is printed.

If you disassemble `f1`, you'll see the byte codes

```
   7          20 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (f2)
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (f3)
             24 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (f4)
             26 LOAD_GLOBAL              5 (f5)
             28 LOAD_GLOBAL              6 (f1)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             38 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             40 POP_TOP
```

The byte code executor has its own stack. Some byte codes put things on the stack, some take things from the stack and replace them with some resulting value. Here, all of the functions are loaded onto the stack and then a series `CALL_FUNCTION` byte codes pop and call the top thing on the stack. First `f1`, then `f2` and etc.

Python's "recursion count" is really a stack depth count. If it gets big, like 1000 calls big, that's likely a recursion problem, hence the name. In your first example, calls to `f2`, etc increase the stack count faster than `f1` increases the count. But in your second example, because `f1` calls `f1` before any other funtion, `cnt` goes up at the same rate as the stack count.

The reason why you don't quite reach 10 is that there is already some stuff on the stack by the time your code runs.

Comment: After f1 is modified to exit e.g. at depth 4 *with no RecursionError* **all of the nested f2,f3,f4,f5 are executed the number of times f1 was previously run**. But the calls to them seem to be stacked elsewhere not on the recursion stack. *Please provide in your answer also the explanation where are all these calls stacked for later execution?* It can't be in the compiled code itself as the code can't know how many times the f1 will be run. And it seems not to be the stack with the call frames ...

Comment: Added explainer. There is indeed a second stack controlled by the byte code executor that holds temporary values about to be consumed by future byte codes. "add" for instance, would push 2 values to add, then BINARY_ADD would pop those two values and push the result of the add.