# Why each thread get a new copy of packageManager object? How can I only use one?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I am building a distributed spider in python, there is a problem with the code. I created an packagemanager object outside, and pass it to gensismanager.py, and i created 4 threads based on 4 functions in gensismanager. but when each of them calling self.packagemanaer, they are calling different object, they got their own copy of that. Why?
How can I only share one copy of that?
Thanks!

in GensisManamger.py

```
class GensisManager(object):
    host_ip = '192.168.1.118'
    host_port = 10001
    authkey = 'pathea'

    def __init__(self, service, packageManager):
        self.logManager = LogManager(service)
        self.packageFactory = PackageFactory()
        self.service = service
        self.dataWrapper = DataWrapper()
        self.cnames = DataTypeNames()
        self.analyzeManager = AnalyzeManager(self.service)
        self.packageManager = packageManager
        print('init pack ', self.packageManager)

    def start_gensisManager_master(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        def _get_task_queue():
            return task_queue
        def _get_result_queue():
            return result_queue

        BaseManager.register('get_task_queue', callable = _get_task_queue)
        BaseManager.register('get_result_queue', callable = _get_result_queue)
        # BaseManager.register('_get_ownership_queue', callable = _get_ownership_result_queue)

        manager = BaseManager(address = (self.host_ip, self.host_port), authkey = self.authkey.encode('utf-8'))
        print('[GS] Usernet service created.')
        return manager

    def setStatTool(self, statTool):
        self.statTool = statTool

    def package_manager_process_distribute(self, datas, task_queue, wait_queue):
        # check logger for breakpoint(new packages)
        if datas is None:
            sys.exit('[GS] Error: no packages to start.')

        initData = datas[self.cnames.data]
        initStat = datas[self.cnames.stat]
        # init packages with found packages or new packages
        self.packageManager.add_new_packages(initData)
        print('aaaaa', self.packageManager)
        if initStat != None:
            self.analyzeManager.initStatFromOldStat(initStat)

        print('[GS] Package distributor thread running.......')
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

            while self.packageManager.has_new_package():
                # get new package from manager and send it to task queue awaiting for slaves
    #            new_package = packageManager.get_new_package()
                # NEED PACKAGE GENERATOR
                # PUT IN A PACKAGE
    #            task_queue.put(new_package)
                # add work end conditions. end code not completed
                break

            while not wait_queue.empty():
                print('[GS] Added a failed package to task queue.')
                package = wait_queue.get()
                self.packageManager.remove_visited_package(package)

    def package_manager_process_collect(self, conn_queue):
        print('[GS] Package collector thread running.......')
        print('ccc', self.packageManager)
        while True:
            while not conn_queue.empty():
                try:
                    datas = conn_queue.get()
                    package_manager.add_new_packages(datas)
                except BaseException as e:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
```

in Gensis.py

```
packageManager = PackageManager(service)
    print('ssss', packageManager)
    manager = GensisManager(service, packageManager)



datas = manager.loadInitData()
package_manager_process_distribute = Process(target = manager.package_manager_process_distribute, args = (datas, task_queue, wait_queue,))
package_manager_process_collect = Process(target = manager.package_manager_process_collect, args = (conn_queue,))
result_analysis_process = Process(target = manager.result_analysis_process, args = (result_queue, conn_queue, store_queue, wait_queue,))
store_process = Process(target = manager.store_process, args = (store_queue,))

package_manager_process_distribute.start()
package_manager_process_collect.start()
result_analysis_process.start()
store_process.start()

package_manager_process_distribute.join()
package_manager_process_collect.join()
result_analysis_process.join()
store_process.join()
```

Comment: Please can you also share the code that sets up the threads/tasks?

Comment: I have posted the setup code. thanks!

Comment: Can you show us how/why you think they are using different package manager objects?

Comment: When I print the hex(id(self.packageManager)) in GensisManager.py, they print out different address. Also, when I calling self.packageManager from threads other than distributing thread(the first one), they would see the contents as nil, which does not reflect the content change of that in the first thread

Comment: Hmm, that does seem odd. I'd probably add something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-from-a-method-in-python-code into the package manager class init ,so that you can see when and where the other package managers are being created.

Comment: Thanks I ll try that. This is one of the weirdest situation i have never met. so weird