# Python - Capture all possible code paths from one function to another function

Tags: python, parsing, linter

Let's say in a python project there are 2 functions `func_a()` and `func_b()`. The 2 functions may not be in the same file or same folder (but are a part of the same project). What we want to find out is all possible ways using which we can call `func_b()` from `func_a()`, without actually running the code. The answer can be something like

```
func_a() -> mid_func_1() -> mid_func_2() -> func_b()
func_a() -> mid_func_3() -> mid_func_4() -> mid_func_4() -> func_b()
```

Basically, I am asking for a tool that can do a DFS from `func_a` to `func_b`, without actually running the code.

Is it possible to do in let's say PyCharm or any other tool?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print current call stack from a method in Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-from-a-method-in-python-code)

Comment: Seems like something you might be able to build using `astroid`.