# How does one step into or print detailed stack trace during call of python method

Tags: python, debugging

Let's say I call a function, say extractall from zipfile module.

How would I see all calls to other functions extractall is making? e.g. similar to step into, or a stack trace?

Comment: if you raise an exception you should get a full stacktrace

Comment: Use [a debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)?

Comment: maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-from-a-method-in-code