# Python equivalent of Jstack?

Tags: python

Is there a python equivalent of jstack? I've got a hung process and I really want to see what it's up to because I have yet to reproduce the defect in development.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Python GDB](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)

Comment: This is most useful when you compile the python interpreter with debug symbols, but I was still able to use it to track down my problem, thanks.