# Python thread dump

Tags: python

Is there a way to get a thread dump from a running Python process?
Similar to kill -3 on a Java process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I havent seen anything built-in, but I have seen [a solution here](http://bzimmer.ziclix.com/2008/12/17/python-thread-dumps/) which can be exposed via http console.  The solution iterates over all threads and outputs the stack.

Comment: So the answer is that Python doesn't have this mechanism built in, right?

Comment: I'm running this in Pylons via Apache, and the problem is that each process runs a single thread.  So, the thread-dump is always for the thread that called for a dump, and so is always identical, and useless.

Answer (score 2):

As this is an old question, but it is number one in Google, so let me answer.

Python has had a [faulthandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) module for some time now (a decade or so). This is a built-in way to give you a thread dump of any running Python process.