# Is there any thread dump method with Python like Java thread dump?

Tags: python, multithreading

Currently I want to find any Python tool can let me monitor another Python process' threads status. I know there is already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302991/python-thread-dump)

But the solution does not work in my case as it only dumps the process' own threads status.

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no built-in support for this, but I've wanted it myself as well, and that's why I wrote [my "PDM" library](http://www.dolda2000.com/~fredrik/pdm/). Maybe you'll find it useful as well.

Comment: Hi, currently I want to figure out why the target Python process runs strangely slow in some case. Is the tool suitable to do this?

Comment: If you can do that with a stack dump, it certainly can be used for it. Just attach with `pdm-repl` to the process, `import pdm.util` and check `pdm.util.traces()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is something that I tried to monitor thread statuses in python. This code instruments the python code and may hamper performance overall. Since I wrote this code for my company it is proprietary and I can't post it on SO. But to your question whether one can output thread status of another python process, the answer is a resounding yes.

Comment: Thank you! Hope I can also do it:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing and running the [psutils](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library.