# Print into output window in Komodo

Tags: python, windows, debugging, komodo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Komodo - watch variables and execute code while on pause in the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711193/komodo-watch-variables-and-execute-code-while-on-pause-in-the-program)

I am using Komodo IDE with `Debug in separate console window` option in order to debug curses based program. So the output goes to console window. However, I also need to print something into Komodo output window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [runEncodedCommand](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/komodo-js-api.html#ko.run) in a [macro](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macros.html#macros_writing) to print to the Komodo command output window:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(2);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); }

var foo = "echo " + typeof(ko);
ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, foo); // Prints object;
```

Comment: But this is JavaScript. I was looking to print from Python program.

Comment: There's a [Python Macro API](http://community.activestate.com/forum/python-macro-access-command-output-window) that can print as well. I hope that helps.

Comment: I came across that thread but unfortunately I can't use it due to error not finding `xpcom` module and I'm not sure how to install it.

Comment: If you're running the code inside the console window, xpcom is not in that namespace. Try adding the macro to the [Toolbox](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macros.html#macros_writing) and assigning a key binding to run it while the console window is open.

Comment: Running macro manually is not what I want. I need to print debug output from within program.

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711193/) exists with an answer that may be acceptable.