# How to force python's VM to print a stack trace?

Tags: python, debugging

I'm dealing with a python-written server that locks up, and stops working, including logging. I wonder if there's a python equivalent to java's "kill -3" signal that at least prints the current stacktrace.

Comment: `kill -2` sends SIGINT, which at least on Linux seems to translate into a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. That might cause a stack trace to be dumped somewhere. It depends on the server of course.

Answer (score 7):

Use the **faulthandler** module.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.register(signal.SIGUSR1)
```

This works outside of Python's interpreter loop's signal handling at the C level so it will work even when the Python interpreter itself is hung waiting on something else.

See also: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/faulthandler

Comment: As you hint, `faulthandler` is included in the standard library from Python 3.3+

Answer (score 2):

```
import signal, traceback
def quit_handler(signum,frame):
    traceback.print_stack()
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT,quit_handler)
```

Comment: If the server "locks up", it doesn't necessarily get a SIGQUIT signal, I guess.

Comment: @AndiDog: I think you're supposed to use `kill(1)` to send it one when you manually detect that it has locked up.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a (Unix-only) solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application).