# python introspection - how to detect the object i am in

Tags: python, introspection

Suppose I have a free function which has been called from a class method. Is there a way for me to introspect the call stack in the free function and determine what object called me?

```
def foo(arg1) :
  s = ? #Introspect call stack and determine what object called me
  # Do something with s
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application
For your scenario I would recommend using http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to make `foo` part of a class and remove all doubt about the object invoking the method?

Comment: I am also very curious to know why it would be needed ? why can't u just pass the calling object as argument?

Comment: Doing this is a horrible, horrible idea. You're trying to defeat one of the core principles of structured programming.

Comment: Agreed, add another parameter to foo which passes in the object that called it.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really the concept of "a calling **object**".  You can introspect the stack and find if your calling **function** has a first argument named `self`, I guess -- if you're called directly from a normally-coded *instance* method (absolutely **not** a [*class* method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) as you say... I imagine you're just horribly mis-speaking, because the very *purpose* of a `classmethod` is to **not** have "an object", i.e. an instance, involved!-), that should detect that.

The [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#module-inspect) module offers you the tools for advanced introspection (recommended **only** for debugging and development purposes, **never** for "actual production use"!!!).  However, note that even tracing the *function* is not trivial: you get *stack frames* which point to the code object (which *doesn't* point back to the function).

Still, it *can* be arranged, because there are pseudo-dicts of local variables also pointed from stack frames, and arguments are local variables, so what you're looking for is an entry in the local variables of your caller's stack frame that is named `self` (and in addition of course you need a lot of optimism and a smidgeon of luck as nobody *forces* your caller to be coded sensibly -- the argument normally named `self` *could* be named otherwise, and then you're in trouble;-).

Comment: a good point regarding the class method mentioned, even other languages include this nomenclature for methods that aren't bound to an instance

Comment: @Matt, yep, I believe we borrowed the name (and concept) from Smalltalk in particular.