# debugging with python trace

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, import, trace

I have a python 2.7 application, which uses multiple threads. I currently run into a bug that there is some sort of infinite loop somewhere in one of the threads. Reading about this, I tried to run python with `-m trace` to trace where the loop is coming from ([compare post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443607/how-can-i-tell-where-my-python-script-is-hanging)).

When I run the application with `-m trace` I get an import error. If I run it without `-m trace` I do not get an import error. Any idea why and how else I should debug the application?

**things I already tried for debugging:**

- stepping through the app with vs code debuggin. Does not work, because it hangs in some other thread.
- using `-m trace`. Compare above
- using prints. Might work, but is not a good solution, because the application is quite large

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) and following all writing activity of my code. The exact command I used was `strace -e trace=write my_script.py &> output.txt`.

I would recommend to write the output to a file, because strace is quite verbose.