# Python script getting stuck in between without any trace

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a python script which is threaded and runs on our server node . The Problem is that the script gets stuck/hanged without any trace.
How to check where the script is hanging as it doesn't print anything

Comment: Without your code, we can only theorise. Update your original post with the code.

Comment: But the code is company property so I cannot post it   But I can tell the functionality of it

Comment: Change variable names and post the code, nobody can be much of a help without the actual code

Comment: Plent of answers on this site on how to debug. Research some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443607/how-can-i-tell-where-my-python-script-is-hanging

Comment: Thanks I saw these links but my problem is the code works fine for 3-4 days in continuously but it hangs in between and debugging it very difficult as it has 2000 lines of code

Comment: "debugging is very difficult". Welcome to programming. Actually guess what: It's even harder when we don't have the code.

Comment: yes I understand but I cannot put my code otherwise i will lose my job

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [hanging_threads](https://pypi.org/project/hanging_threads/) module (available from PyPI) - It might give you some pointers on where your code gets stuck. However it is prone to false positives (e.g. if your script waits for a network connection).