# Pycryptodome Python3 RSA.importKey blocking/hangs

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, rsa, pycryptodome

I am running Python 3.5.2 with the latest version of Pycryptodome.

When importing my RSA private key using `RSA.importKey` there is an infinite hang or block. I've tried to step through the lib and cannot find any reason why.

The private key is an RSA private key in PEM format. i.e. I am passing a byte array of the key.

I get no exceptions just a hang making message signing impossible.
Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with a solution?
If it helps, this is running on Linux.

Comment: Maybe try the `importkey` method? See if it does anything different.

Answer (score 0):

One neat solution is taken from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443607/how-can-i-tell-where-my-python-script-is-hanging/3443779) and it is based on [lptrace](http://khamidou.com/lptrace/). You get the PID of the python process and then run:

```
sudo python lptrace -p $STUCK_PROGRAM_PID
```

Once you have identified at least the offending line, you can log a bug on the [project's page](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/) and get more help there.