# How to use the active state recipe for debugging?

Tags: python, debugging

I  came across [this active state recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576515-debugging-a-running-python-process-by-interrupting/) on seeing [this answer on 'How to find where a running python program is getting hung?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6728290/7952027).
I admit I am a noob at python. How to make use of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have saved the active state recipe as 'hung.py' in the same folder as the original hung program.

- Get the process id (pid) of the hung python program. say 123 (Hint: Use htop)
- Go to a terminal and type `python hung.py 123`  (Use the correct pid instead of 123 )
- You are done.