# Can I see what code is currently running on a python process?

Tags: python

To introduce my question let get an example.

I have a file `code.py`. Let's say I run it, `python code.py` which takes some time. Python starts a process, call it `p0`.

Obviously changing `code.py` during `p0` won't change its execution, because the code, `code.py` is loaded at the begining.

My point is then: is there a way, knowing `p0`'s `pid` to see/print the python code **currently used** by `p0` i.e. `code.py`'s "version" when `p0` started?

I'm quite curious about how difficult this could be, and, as python isn't a compiled language, I think there may be the original python source, somewhere. Plus, it's quite hacky, but this could help me when I'm not 100% sure how was the code when I started a looooong process (then modified the file, yes that's not a really good pratice, must say).

Any clue?
thx folks

`pltrdy`

Comment: attach debugger gdb to the pid

Comment: Is it a thread or a system execution call you're referring to as `p0`?

Comment: @vks i'll look @ gdb for python. I know that we can get trace + infos about variables. Not sure about printing the code itself, but this can help anyway.

@Torxed: `p0` is the process started by `python` command. Is it clear?

Comment: once gdb is attached you can actually see what part of code is executing at moment........also if it has threads u can see which thread etc

Comment: As you can change the original code itself, you can use the method on http://stackoverflow.com/a/25329467/2591803 to add the ability to send signals to get a pdb debugger session.

This won't work with currently running processes but should be easier than using gdb for the future.