# Python - attaching to project half way thru the execution

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging

Google'd but only getting results about how we can create launch.json configs and start the debugging from line #1.

So I have a [big?] Python project that runs from command-line, and I just created a helper method (`def pauseHereAndNotifyUserOnSlack(user=<username>`) to pause where needed and wait for the user to press a key to exit out of this [infinite] loop and resume the code.

I am wondering if there's a way to attach my python project while the code is paused, inspect the variables and stuff, and resume execution from there?

(Think C#/C++ has this feature, where they attach using symbols and stuff? Not 100% sure how this works. Maybe I am confusing myself?)

Let me know if you guys need more clarification. TIA

Comment: I am curious about what you mean by " attach my python project ".

Comment: pdb does not have the ability to halt and begin debugging on a running program.

You can read more about it in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308847/attaching-a-process-with-pdb

Comment: Thank you @DDay. Your link gave me pointers in finding the answer I am looking for. Somehow I landed on this video and it is exactly what I am looking for - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZJnGOwzHtU&loop=0

Comment: @kgkmeekg Found what I am looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZJnGOwzHtU&loop=0. Was thinking there's a way I can somehow connect vscode with my Python project open to the same project running in cmdline and resume code from some breakpoint. But this video helped me - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZJnGOwzHtU&loop=0

Comment: Learnt something new today! Is there any specific reason you are not using PyCharm and the python debugger that comes with it ?

Comment: This project is run from command line on CI, for each PR

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to debug your code from line 1, set breakpoints in your code and start debugging from there and inspect variables and can also resume execution from there. (if this is what you were talking about)
> the play button can be used to resume your execution.[image: example given below]

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. Found what I am looking for in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZJnGOwzHtU&loop=0