# How to intercept running python script and execute command within its context?

Tags: python, debugging, cpython, intercept

Here is the situation (as an example) - I ran a ML learning python script (which I wrote) for a long time but I didn't add functionality to save its weights.

My question in this situation is if it's possible to somehow intercept the running python interpreter and execute a command within the program context.

For example since I have `model_seq` global variable inside the running program - I would like to execute:

```
model_seq.save_weights("./model_weights")
```

Inside the process.

I've heard this is somewhat possible with gdb.

(Personally I know this can be done for sure with a C program and gdb - but since Python is compiled and interpreted the steps are a bit unclear for me (and I'm not sure if I would actually need a special python3 build or the default ubuntu one I have running will work))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attaching a process with pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308847/attaching-a-process-with-pdb)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It kinda does thanks.