# Disable AppArmor for Docker for ptrace_scope

Tags: linux, docker, gdb, ptrace, apparmor

Is it possible to disable AppArmor for a particular Docker container? I want to make ptrace accessible so I can attach gdb to a running process but run into the following issue when I want to change the setting:

```
root@fbf728150308:/gopath# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 12):

AppArmor can be disabled either by running unconfined, or as a privileged container:

- `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined` (or `apparmor:unconfined` for docker 1.10 and below)
- `--privileged`

However, a better option is to create a new profile that enables ptrace. You can use the docker AppArmor profile as a starting point (found in `/etc/apparmor.d/docker`), and append the `ptrace peer=@{profile_name}`.

You will also need to disable seccomp (unless using `privileged`), through `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined`

Comment: See also `docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Comment: `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` does not seem to exist anymore in Docker > v1.13

Comment: @Peter, I installed the snap version and that would be under the `/snap/...` but it's not there either. It would be good to have a copy of that file (or a link to it).

Comment: I found it, it's under a separate folder (i.e. not `/etc/...`) `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker`. That makes sense since we want to be able to edit these files and all `/snap/...` are read-only.