# Run docker build in privileged LXC containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, lxc

In PVE, a privileged LXC container has been opened, and `lxc.apparmor.profile: unconfined` has been added to its configuration. Docker is also running inside this container. Privileged Docker containers are run with `--privileged`, and non-privileged Docker containers are run with `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined`, both of which work fine. Now, when attempting to run `docker build` with the `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined` option, the following error occurs:

```
#8 0.339 runc run failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/apparmor/exec: no such file or directory
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the latest Proxmox GUI, but when I create my privileged LXC container with Ubuntu18.04 LTS on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS host via bash directly, I add the next lines to my container config:

```
# cat /var/lib/lxc/my_container_name/config

lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.apparmor.profile = unconfined
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = a
lxc.cap.drop =
security.nesting = true
security.privileged = true

# ...
```

to make working nested containers possible.

Using these lines all priveleged/non-priveleged docker containers up to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Debian 12, or RHEL9 works fine inside LXC container.

It's also possible to nest containers in your LXC two times (yeah, sounds scary, but we use it to test your ansible roles). So we run docker in lxc-nested docker and lxc inside lxc-nested docker with:

- `SYS_ADMIN` capabilities;
- `/run`, `/tmp` and `/run/lock` tmpfs;
- `/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw` (or set `:ro`) bind mount from the host where docker runs.

In this setup we have never seen error messages about `/proc/self/attr/apparmor`. Googling a bit [brought an answer](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/3831) that your apparmor failed to apply profile. This way you should try:

1. `apparmor_status` command to ensure your apparmor is started. If you don't need an apparomor you can also disable them `systemctl stop apparmor` to stop apparmor daemon and/or:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/default/grub.d
   $ echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT apparmor=0"' \
     | sudo tee /etc/default/grub.d/apparmor.cfg
   $ sudo update-grub
   $ sudo reboot
   ```

   (from [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse))
2. Run `lxc-start <container-name> --logfile <log_name>; cat <log_name>` directly from your host to see what's happened on container start. If your PVE controls containers over LXD you should use `lxc start <container-name> --logfile <log_name>` command instead.
3. If you're on Debian 12, looks like you also need a line `lxc.apparmor.allow_incomplete = 1` in your container config (see ['**lxc-start fails since debian 12.x upgrade (proxmox CT + nested lxc**'](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/4342)). So add them to your `/var/lib/lxc/<my_container_name>/config` file.
4. For troubleshooting reason, you can also try `lxc.mount.entry = /sys/kernel/security sys/kernel/security none bind,optional 0 0` line in your container config (see '**[Apparmor inside Debian container](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/apparmor-inside-debian-container/10332)**'
5. You can also run your nested docker with `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072468/disable-apparmor-for-docker-for-ptrace-scope)). Perhaps you also need to disable seccomp (unless using privileged), through `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072468/disable-apparmor-for-docker-for-ptrace-scope#39277945)).
6. Running all listed commands via terminal and changing configs directly, **please compare them with Proxmox changes via GUI.**