# Check what a running process is doing: print stack trace of an uninstrumented Python program

Tags: python, debugging, process, daemon, stack-trace

Is there a way on Linux to check what a running Python daemon process is doing? That is, without instrumenting the code and without terminating it? Preferably I'd like to get the name of the module and the line number in it that is currently running.

Conventional debugging tools such as strace, pstack and gdb are not very useful for Python code. Most stack frames just contain functions from the interpreter code like PyEval_EvalFrameEx and and PyEval_EvalCodeEx, it doesn't give you any hint on were in the .py-file the execution is.

Comment: related https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Answer (score 11):

Some of the answers in [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application) are applicable in this situation:

- [pyrasite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application#29881630) (this was the one that worked for me):

  ```
  $ sudo pip install pyrasite
  $ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
  $ sudo pyrasite 16262 dump_stacks.py # dumps stacks to stdout/stderr of the python program
  ```
- [pyringe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application#23405280)
- [pydbattach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application#10047855) - couldn't get this to work, but the repository https://github.com/albertz/pydbattach contains pointer to other tools
- [pstack reportedly prints the python stack on Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application#7224091)

Comment: If you want to use pyrasite and gdb in a Docker container, then you need to run the container with the following flags: `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --privileged` and you need to exec into the container as root (even if a dedicated app user runs the process in the container) for which you will need: `docker exec -it --user root -w=/root [container id] bash`

Comment: What is `dump_stacks.py`? When I run these commands with pyrasite installed nothing happens. Pyrasite just exits silently.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist it's [one of the sample payloads](https://github.com/lmacken/pyrasite/blob/master/pyrasite/payloads/dump_stacks.py). I'm not the best person to help you troubleshoot this, so perhaps a separate question is warranted.

Comment: I  cannot accept the answer if I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist sorry, didn't realize you were the OP. Still as this worked for me 6 years ago, the answer might help someone even if not marked as accepted...

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist probably too late, but: use `--verbose` to see the problem; in my case, I had to install `gdb`

Answer (score 4):

py-spy (https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) has a few useful tools for inspecting running Python processes. In particular, `py-spy dump` will print a stack trace (including function, file, and line) for every thread.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

winpdb allows you to [attach to a running python process](http://winpdb.org/docs/launch-time/), but to do this, you must start the python process this way:

```
 rpdb2 -d -r script.py
```

Then, after setting a password:

```
A password should be set to secure debugger client-server communication.
Please type a password:mypassword
```

you could launch winpdb to File>Attach to (or File>Detach from) the process.

Answer (score 2):

on POSIX systems like Linux, you can use good old GDB, see

- https://t37.net/debug-a-running-python-process-without-printf.html
  and
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

There's also the excellent PyCharm IDE (free community version available) that can attach to a running Python process right from within the IDE, using Pdb 4 under the hood, see this blog entry:

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/02/feature-spotlight-python-debugger-and-attach-to-process/

Answer (score 1):

[lptrace](http://khamidou.com/lptrace/) does exactly that. It allows you to attach to a running Python process and show currently executing functions, like `strace` does for system calls. You can call it like this:

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ sudo python lptrace -p $YOUR_PID
fileno (/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py:438)
meth (/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py:223)

fileno (/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py:438)
meth (/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py:223)
...
```

Note that it requires gdb to run, which isn't available on every server machine.

Comment: Not work in python3, this fork works fine https://github.com/seppo0010/lptrace

Answer (score 1):

You can use [madbg](https://github.com/kmaork/madbg) (by me). It is a python debugger that allows you to attach to a running python program and debug it in your current terminal. It is similar to `pyrasite` and `pyringe`, but newer, doesn't require gdb, and uses `IPython` for the debugger (which means colors and autocomplete).

To see the stack trace of a running program, you could run:

```
madbg attach <pid>
```

And in the debugger shell, enter:
`bt`

Comment: Worked for me on the first try, while pyrasite (topvoted solution at the time of writing) didn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to debug Python with gdb. See [Chapter 22: gdb Support](https://devguide.python.org/gdb/) in the Python Developer’s Guide.

For example, on Debian with Python 3.7:

```
# apt-get update -y && apt-get install gdb python3.7-dbg
# gdb

(gdb) source /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.7-gdb.py
(gdb) attach <PID>
(gdb) py-bt
```

Comment: What is python3.7-dbg? I'm using Arch Linux and I don't think I have a corresponding package.

Comment: Not sure about Arch Linux but this page (outdated) mentions some other distros… see "Debugging Python with gdb 101": https://www.podoliaka.org/2016/04/10/debugging-cpython-gdb/

Comment: You might try simply `python-dbg`: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python-dbg/

Comment: There is something wrong with that AUR package and I could't install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [satella](https://pypi.org/project/satella/) to do this. A nice side effect will be that every local variable in every stack frame will be printed out. The code would be:

```
from satella.instrumentation import Traceback
import sys

for frame_no, frame in sys._current_frames().items():
    sys.stderr.write("For stack frame %s" % (frame_no,))
    tb = Traceback(frame)
    tb.pretty_print()
sys.stderr.write("End of stack frame dump\n")
```

Comment: How can this be applied to an already running python process?