# __new__() missing 1 required positional argument depending of url scraped

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pickle

I have a weird error and I will try to simplify my problem.
I have a simple function that scraps an url with beautiful soup and returns a list. 
Then, I pickle the list in file, so I *setrecursionlimit(10000)* to avoid *RecursionError*. Until there, everything is good.

But when I try to unpickle my list, I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\scrap_index.py", line 86, in <module>
    data_file = pickle.load(data)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

There is my function:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrap_function(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")   

    return [soup]
```

For testing, I've tried different url.
With that url, everything is good:

```
url_ok = 'https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/'
```

But with that one, I have the TypeError:

```
url_not_ok = 'https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/actions'
```

And the test code:

```
import pickle
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

scrap_list = scrap_function(url_not_ok)

with open('test_saving.pkl', 'wb') as data:
    pickle.dump(scrap_list, data, protocol=2)

with open('test_saving.pkl', 'rb') as data:
    data_file = pickle.load(data)

print(data_file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://bugs.python.org/issue18359) states

> If some class objects have extra arguments in the **new** constructor
>   , pickle fail to serialize it.

This could cause the problem [here](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py#L676) in beautifulsoap:

```
class NavigableString(unicode, PageElement):
    def __new__(cls, value):
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24563670/7919597) states the same.

As a solution do not store the whole object but maybe only the source code of the page as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24664473/7919597).

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But if that, why is it working with some urls ?

Comment: I've found the solution in your links ! It was an encoding problem. Just have to `return [str(soup)]` to not have a `NavigableString`. Thank you !