# Why is attribute information added during __new__ lost during pickling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a float subclass defined as follows:

```
class NewFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, value2):
        r = super().__new__(cls, value)
        r.value = value2
        return r
```

When I create an instance of this class, all works well -- `a = NewFloat(1, 2)` gives an object `a` such that `a.value` returns `2`. However, when I pickle the object (`pickle.dump(a, open('file.p', 'wb'))`) and try to load it (`pickle.load(open('file.p', 'rb'))`), it throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-ff08f7f793b8> in <module>
----> 1 b = pickle.load(open('test_pickle.p', 'rb'))

TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value2'
```

What is going on during the pickling process that causes this error? Is `__new__` called again, and why?

I've found that adding the attribute in a function definition works fine, but I can't see why this should be any different:

```
class NewFloat2(float):
    def save_value(self, value):
        r.value = value
```

A `NewFloat2` instance can be pickled and loaded, no problem. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue18359 may help you

Comment: Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24664473/259889

Answer (score 0):

Typically, upon pickling, `obj.__class` and `obj.__dict__` are saved, and upon unpickleing `cls.__new__(cls)` and `cls.__dict__.update(attrs)` are executed.

That is to say, `pickle` won't pass extra args to your `__new__()` method while unpickling by default. To solve this, you must define the `__getnewargs__()` method in your class to tell `pickle` to pass those args, such as:

```
class NewFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, value2):
        r = super().__new__(cls, value)
        r.value = value2
        r.original_value = value
        return r
    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return (self.original_value,self.value)
```

Then the `pickle` will appear as you want. You define `__getnewargs_ex__()` method if you want to pass keyword args too,

Note that the `value` argument is useless and unsaved in the instance in such an example. When it goes to normal application, you either save it in a property of the instances or remove it.