# Multiprocessing Large Objects Using Pathos in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, dill, pathos

I am trying to make use of my computer's multiple CPUs. However, the `BeautifulSoup` object returned by my function as part of an `SQLAlchemy` object  [is not picklable with pickle or cPickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563148/beautifulsoup-object-will-not-pickle-causes-interpreter-to-silently-crash) so I am using [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos), a fork of the `multiprocssing` package that uses `dill` such that it can pickle any python object. I tested dill on the object that I could not pickle and it worked, so I thought my problem would be solved. However, when I use pathos' `pool.map` I have [the same problem that I did before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537379/python-multiprocessing-script-freezes-seemingly-without-error), mainly that the function completes but the result is not returned. I confirmed this by using `results = pool.amap(myfunc, myarglist)` which completes, but `results.get()` which does not.  Unfortunately, I cannot post the html for the page (it is not publicly available), and I have been unable to find a reproducible example of the problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855207/2327821) includes a function for troubleshooting multiprocessing of large objects, but unfortunately it uses `Queue` which does not seem to be implemented for `pathos` by itself (only presumably under the hood within the `pool.map` function). I am using the `0.2a1.dev` version of pathos (with dependencies installed with pip prior to compiling from source) on python 2.7. Here is the traceback for the keyboard interrupt:

```
Process PoolWorker-2:
Process PoolWorker-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process PoolWorker-8:Process PoolWorker-6:Process PoolWorker-3:Process PoolWorker-5:Process PoolWorker-4:Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap



Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 59, in worker
    self.run()
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 54, in worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 54, in worker
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 54, in worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
    put((job, i, result))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 339, in put
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 54, in worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 54, in worker
    for job, i, func, args, kwds in iter(inqueue.get, None):
    for job, i, func, args, kwds in iter(inqueue.get, None):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 325, in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 325, in get
    wacquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    for job, i, func, args, kwds in iter(inqueue.get, None):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 325, in get
    racquire()
    racquire()
    for job, i, func, args, kwds in iter(inqueue.get, None):
    for job, i, func, args, kwds in iter(inqueue.get, None):
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 325, in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 325, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    racquire()
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 227, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/process.py", line 85, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.py", line 54, in worker
    for job, i, func, args, kwds in iter(inqueue.get, None):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 327, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: I'd suggest you update to the most recent pathos from github, I'm unsure if that will help you or not. Also are you using `pathos.multiprocessing.Pool` or `ProcessingPool`?  `Pool` uses `dill` instead of `pickle`, but doesn't have the rest of the augments that `ProcessingPool` has.  If your function is calling `Queue` as you have indicated elsewhere, you may be out of luck.  You could possibly use shared memory in `multiprocessing` with `ctypes`.  I don't know, hard to say without seeing your code.  There is an option in `dill` that provides compression, but it's turned off at the moment...

Comment: 0.2a1.dev is not the most recent version? I installed from github source this morning. My function does not call queue, only multiprocessing. I was using `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool` which is used in the pathos documentation. Doesn't that not use `dill`? At any rate I just tried `pathos.multiprocessing.Pool` and got the same result.

Comment: Whoops. I didn't see your version info in the question. Sorry.  Yes, that uses `dill`, both do.  You are using it as intended, it seems.  Sorry for my confusion.  Looks the size of the pickle causes an issue, as your trace says.  `dill` and `pathos` have some compression options that I could try, given an example.  There's also shared memory as I mentioned.

Comment: Where is that indicated in the trace? Other than shared memory, is there a workaround within the `pathos` multiprocessing package to pickle large objects differently? The biggest issue for me is that because the script simply hangs I cannot figure out how to catch this as an error so my script crashes.

Comment: I just tested dill on one of the object that crashes and it turns out it does not work. When I call `dill.dumps(myobject)` it hangs.

Comment: I have compression turned off in `dill`, but it is exposed in another package. It's hard to tell if it's compression or size, or what without seeing a sample.  Would it be possible to post or send the code?

Comment: I still have never seen `dill` just hang on a `dump`.  There are several methods to try in `dill.detect` that give you information on what is happening.  If you still can't post a reduced example of your code for whatever reason, you could at least try some of the `dill.detect` methods, and maybe find some clue to what the error is.

Comment: I fixed it by getting rid of the attributes of the object that could not be pickled using cPickle and just using the main multiprocessing package. Sorry I cannot help you reproduce the error to debug the package, but if you've never seen an issue it cannot be affecting that many people. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24664473/2327821

Comment: If you got rid of the unpicklable attributes of your object ahead of time, then there is no need for `dill` or `pathos.multiprocessing`…  `cPickle` would simply work.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.