# Why do processes take long time to join even when the map call to pool is completed?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, zombie-process

This is yet another question regarding `multiprocessing` module in `Python 3.`5. My problem is that I know all the forked processed have done their job (I can see their result in `Queue`), the AsyncResult.result() returns True which means that jobs are completed but when I proceed with PoolObj.join(), it takes forever. I know I can PoolObj.terminate() and carry on with my life, but I want to know why the heck does this happen?

I'm using following code:

```
def worker(d):
    queue.put(d)

def gen_data():
    for i in range(int(1e6)):
        yield i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue(maxsize=-1)
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    pool_obj_worker = pool.map_async(worker, gen_data(), chunksize=1)
    pool.close()

    print ('Lets run the workers...\n')
    while True:
        if pool_obj_worker.ready():
            if pool_obj_worker.successful():
                print ('\nAll processed successfully!') # I can see this quickly, so my jobs are done
            else:
                print ('\nAll processed. Errors encountered!')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            print (q.qsize()) # The size is right that means all workers have done their job
            pool.join() # will get stuck here for long long time
            queue.put('*')           
            break
    print ('%d still to be processed' %
           pool_obj_worker._number_left)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Am I doing it wrong? Please enlighten me. Or are the processes holding `join()` have gone zombie?

Comment: What happens if you reduce the size of what you're trying to put into the queue?

Comment: The issue exists even for smaller values of 1e5 and 1e4. However, for values smaller than these, the issue is not so obvious.

Comment: Reduce it to `10` and try - does it at least complete or is it still hanging? This could be related to [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue8426) and I had a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961584/multiprocesses-become-zombie-processes-when-increasing-iterations-what-is-the-a) but using `Process`. Although, in your case, you're saying the queue is the correct size so there might be something else happening, but it might set you in the right direction. Also, what happens without `.join()` at all?

Comment: Even with 10, join stalls for like 10 secs. I'm using 12 processes and can see them in process monitor even after receiving `True` from `pool_obj_worker.successful()`

Comment: If I use `collections.deque` in place of `multiprocesssing.Queue`, the issue resolves but its of no use as I cannot get my results back. I suppose with every fork a new instance of deque is initialised..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using an extra `Queue` in your worker, other than the one fournished by `Pool`. 
When the processes finish their work, they will all join the `FeederThread` used in the `multiprocessing.Queue` and these calls will hang (probably because all the threads call `join` simultaneously and there can be some weird race conditions, it is not easy to investigate).

Adding `multiprocessing.util.log_to_stderr(10)` permits to reveal that your processes hang while joining the queue feeder thread.

To solve your issue, you can either use `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` instead of `multiprocessing.Queue` (no hang in join as there is no feeder thread) or try using the method `pool.unordered_imap` which provides the same kind of behavior as what you seem to implement (give back an unordered generator containing the results returned by worker).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. You are right! joining Queues has got huge overhead. How can I monitor the progress of job if use pool.imap_unordered?

Comment: An additional related question here! Why do iterations over the imap generator tend to get slower over time. Is it the affect of accumulating results in a list? If so how can I solve this?

Comment: To monitor the progress, you can try accessing `IMapUnorderedIterator._index`

Comment: I don't see any slowdown with the code provided here. Each time you access an element of the generator, it is removed from the list so if it is balanced, it should not really slowdown. Maybe you have bigger object than `int` and the generator grow to big. This depends on your usage..