# Python: Get current line runtime

Tags: python, windows, signals, traceback

In `Python` how to get what block of script is running just right now, **runtime**?

```
print a()             #takes couple of seconds, 3s
print b()             #takes couple of seconds, 3s
pass
print c()             #takes couple of seconds, 4s
print d(), \
      t,y,u,i,o       #takes couple of seconds, 4s
print z
```

So to know (*report*) what is running in the second 7th, for example.

```
report(7s): print c()
```

**EDIT:**

We keep the above as it is to justify the comments given ;) however below we describe our questions in more details.

A `Python` code is being executed line by line (or better block by block). See for example:

in `code.py`:

```
for i in xrange(10000000):                #assume this will take some seconds
   pass

print 'something'
#another time consuming job
for j in xrange(10000000):                #assume this will also take some seconds
   pass

print 'another thing'
```

We were thinking having a **time thread** which samples every 5 seconds to print (i.e., report) *where we are in the code in runtime*. So to have every 5 seconds printing what just happening during the execution.

Example output:

```
>>> 00:05 in progress: "for i in xrange(10000000):..."
>>> 00:10 in progress: "for i in xrange(10000000):..."
>>> 00:15 in progress: "for j in xrange(10000000):..."
...
```

Comment: This question seems really hard to understand to me.  What is your expected output?  What exactly do you mean by the "block of script"?

Comment: Your question is surreal.  "So to know (report) what is running in the second 7th, for example". Report what?  Second 7th of what?  That's no example

Comment: Maybe this is something you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2569696

Comment: Are you saying that you need a duration that took to execute a line, let's say `print "hello"` ?

Comment: @Paco , Vorsprung: See the EDIT.

Comment: @sachitad: We explained it more now.

Comment: Can you wait instead of xrange ?

Comment: @Gcmalloc: Note that `xrange` example is just to **demonstrate a time consuming job**, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fowia(signal, frame):
    print frame.f_lineno


import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, fowia)

for i in xrange(10000000):                
    for k in xrange(100000000):
       pass

print 'something'
#another time consuming job
for j in xrange(10000000):                
        pass
print 'another thing'
```

To use this simple example, start it running then find the pid number of the process from another shell.  Then send a HUP signal to the process.  It will print the current line number.  See http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html for a list of other program source introspection methods that can be used

fowia = find out where I am, btw :)

Comment: I'm afraid `signal.SIGHUP` + others are not available in Windows! We updated tags.