# python mechanize doesn't time out and gets stuck in opening a url

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to open a list of urls, and I set a timeout value to exclude the urls which do not open. However, when I come across the following url, it gets stuck and does not time out. The site opens normally from the browser, so where can the problem be?

```
url='http://www.gizmodo.it/2008/03/12/lo_scanner_di_impronte_digitali_che_distingue_un_dito_vivo_da_unomorto.html'

opener=browser.open(url,timeout=2)
```

Comment: What's the stack trace when you ctrl-c?

Comment: if you're on unix, you can [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133384/1595865) to get a stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page (referenced by the given url) responds with `refresh: 185` header. This cause `HTTPRefreshProcessor` to sleep for 185 seconds; refresh same page; sleep .... (forever).

You can turn off HTTPRefreshProcessor using `set_handle_refresh` method as follow:

```
browser.set_handle_refresh(False) # <-----
browser.open(url, timeout=2.0)
```

Comment: perfect! but if I use that, I won't be able to handle pages that does refresh or redirect?

Comment: @hmghaly, Use another browser instance for other pages if that matter.