# Encryption code in def function to be written in python

Tags: python, validation, input

need some help in the following code as it goes into infinite loop and does not validate user input: the get_offset is the function. Just edited need some help with the encryption part to be done in a function defined

```
def get_offset(offset):
    while True:
        value = (offset)
        if value < 1:
            print("")
        if value > 94:
            print("")
    return offset

my_details = display_details()

get_choice = get_menu_choice()

print(my_details)
print(get_choice)

count = 10

while count > 0:

    count -=1

    encrypted = ""

    choice = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4,5]: "))

    while choice <1 and choice > 5:
        print("Invalid choice, please enter either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.")

    if choice == 1:
        string_input = input("Please enter string to encrypt: ")
        input_offset = get_offset(int(input("Please enter offset value (1 to 94): ")))

   **for letter in string_input:
        x = ord(letter)
        encrypted += chr(x + input_offset)
        if x < 32:
            x += 94
        if x > 126:
            x -= 94

    print(encrypted)**
```

Comment: in your first while loop, you never change "offset" so it is working on the same thing every time ==> infinite loop

Comment: so what needs editing Ali? I am a beginner

Comment: @JaySadat I edited your post for readability. your code needed indentation for markdown support, so that readers can distinguish what you ask and what your code is.

Comment: JaySadat: **it is completely unacceptable to reask the same question twice in a row**: you asked previously on [Apr 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974356/file-decryption-with-ascii/), saying *"Please help me out. I need a quick reply. I would really appreciate it?", I answered. All you did was complain about the answer. Then you reasked yesterday. This sort of behavior gets you banned on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to assign `choice` new value inside inner while loop. this way, new input is considered before iterating again and again.

this should do the trick:

```
while choice < 1 and choice > 5:
    choice = int(input("Invalid choice, please enter either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5."))
```

A random advice: If you want to keep dataset strictly equal to [1,2,3,4,5], you should avoid `choice<1` and `choice>5`. This makes your program vulnerable to invalid inputs such as `3.5`.

Instead, you should do this:

```
valid_inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

choice = int(input("Pick a number from [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:"))

while choice not in valid_inputs:
    choice = int(input("Invalid choice, please enter either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5."))

<rest of stuff here>
```

What I understood from your comments is that, in `get_offset()`, you want user to type a value between 1 and 94. If user enters something out of that range, you want to ask question again and again. The code below should do what you want:

```
def get_offset():
   # first, ask for a value.
   offset = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 94:"))
   while offset < 1 and offset > 94:
      # if the value is invalid, trap user inside this while loop.
      # user will be stuck here (while loop will return true) 
      # until a valid input is received.
      offset = int(input("Invalid input. Please enter a value between 1 and 94:"))
   # if we proceed down here, it means we are over while loop 
   # and it implies that user has given us valid input. return value.
   return offset
```

Secondly, inside main while loop, you can call `get_offset()` like this:

```
if choice == 1:
    string_input = input("Please enter string to encrypt: ")
    input_offset = get_offset()
```

Comment: I am asking about the get_offset in the choice == 1 section

Comment: oh well, I got it wrong. But still, you will be stuck inside that while loop, once you enter an invalid input.

Comment: what do you want to do in `get_offset()`?

Comment: i want to limit the user offset input between 1 and 94. as you see i created a function and used it in the offset input variable but it still does not work

Comment: Can you please be more clear on what you want to do? What do you mean by user offset input? Can you specify your goal with example input and output?

Comment: input_offset = get_offset(int(input("Please enter offset value (1 to 94): ")))

Comment: in the above statement the input must be between  1 and 94 and i need to accomplish that with a function defined as get_offset() as you can see in the code and there is no output displayed, just the input is repeated until a value between 1 and 94 is entered

Comment: I updated the answer for get_offset. I hope I got it right.

Comment: for letter in string_input:
            x = ord(letter)
            encrypted += chr(x + input_offset)

            if x < 32:
                x += 94

            if x > 126:
                x -= 94
                
        print(encrypted)

Comment: Ali Yilmaz brother could you help me out in this final section. I would really appreciate it