# Printing stack trace after a keypress in Python

Tags: python, event-handling, stack-trace, traceback

I have a complex script which does I/O, lots of data processing, communication with external web services, etc.

In some rare cases the script 'hangs'. The CPU is at full 100% load all the time.

I would like to be able to debug the script and find the loop where is 'hangs'. But because it takes 2-3 hours before that loop is reached, I had another idea - print the full stack trace when I press a special key.

Is there a way to attach a keypress event to the script and then I press the right key, then the full stack trace (including where the script was before the keypress) would be printed?

Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: I think logging would work better.

Comment: That is not the question :) Logging is there, but is not enough.

Comment: I found an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application. So far it works :)

Comment: By logging you can have have a complete stacktrace and more. And logging is more robust that signal handling --a busy process might be unable to run the callback. But tbh I didn't even think of using low level signals.

Comment: You can also trigger a stack trace in the code, just before you start the loop (related) code.