# How do I proceed with memory, .so filenames and hex offsets

Tags: python, debugging, system-calls, dtrace

Don't flame me for this but it's genuine. I am writing a multi threaded python application that runs for a very long time, typically 2-3 hours with 10 processes. This machine isn't slow it's just a lot of calculations.

The issue is that sometimes the application will hang about 85-90% of the way there because of outside tools.

I've broken this test up into smaller pieces that can then run successfully but the long running program hangs.

for example let's say I have to analyze some data on a list that 100,000,000 items long.

Breaking it up into twenty 5,000,000 lists all the smaller parts runs to completion.

Trying to do the 100,000,000 project it hangs towards the end. I use some outside tools that I cannot change so I am just trying to see what's going on.

I setup Dtrace and run

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry / execname == "python2.7" / { @[ustack()] = count() }'
```

on my program right when it hangs and I get an output like the code sample below.

```
          libc.so.7`__sys_recvfrom+0xa
          _socket.so`0x804086ecd
          _socket.so`0x8040854ac
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x52d7
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x665
          libpython2.7.so.1`0x800b3317d
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4e2f
          libpython2.7.so.1`0x800b33250
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4e2f
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x665
          libpython2.7.so.1`0x800abb5a1
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyObject_Call+0x64
          libpython2.7.so.1`0x800aa3855
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyObject_Call+0x64
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4de2
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x665
          libpython2.7.so.1`0x800abb5a1
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyObject_Call+0x64
          libpython2.7.so.1`0x800aa3855
          libpython2.7.so.1`PyObject_Call+0x64
```

that code just repeats over and over. I tried looking into the Dtrace python probes but those seems busted two sides from Tuesday so this might be the closest that I'll get.

My question, I have a fuzzy idea that `libpython2.7.so.1` is the shared library that holds the function `pyObject_Call` at an hex offset of 0x64

Is that right?

How can I decipher this? I don't know what to even call this so that I can google for answers or guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably start by reading [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application).

Your specific
question was about the interpretation of DTrace's ustack() action and
so this reply may be more than you need.  This is because one of the
design principles of DTrace is to show the exact state of a system.
So, even though you're interested in the Python aspect of your
program, DTrace is revealing its underlying implementation.

The output you've presented is a stack, which is a way of
describing the state of a thread at a specific point in its
execution.  For example, if you had the code

```
void c(void) { pause(); }
void b(void) { c(); }
void a(void) { b(); }
```

and you asked for a stack whilst execution was within pause() then
you *might* see something like

```
pause()
c()
b()
a()
```

Whatever tool you use will find the current instruction and its
enclosing function before finding the "return address", i.e. the
point to which that function will eventually return; repeating this
procedure yields a stack.  Thus, although the stack should be read
from the top to the bottom as a series of return addresses, it's typically
read in the other direction as a series of callers.  Note that
subtleties in the way that the program's corresponding
instructions are assembled mean that this second interpretation
can sometimes be misleading.

To extend the example above, it's likely that a(), b() and c() are
all present within the same library --- and that there may be
functions with the same names in other libraries.  Thus it's
useful to display, for each function, the object to which it
belongs.  Thus the stack above could become

```
libc.so`pause()
libfoo.so`c()
libfoo.so`b()
libfoo.so`a()
```

This goes some way towards allowing a developer to identify how a
program ended up in a particular state:  function c() in libfoo
has called pause().  However, there's more to be done:  if c()
looked like

```
void c() {
    pause();
    pause();
}
```

then in which call to pause() is the program waiting?

The functions a(), b() and c() will be sequences
of instructions that will typically occupy a contiguous region of
memory.  Calling one of the functions involves little more than
making a note of where to return when finished (i.e. the return
address) and then jumping to whichever memory address corresponds
to the function's start.  Functions' start addresses and sizes are
recorded in a "symbol table" that is embedded in the object;  it's
by reading this table that a debugger is able to find the function
that contains a given location such as a return address.  Thus a
specific point *within* a function can be described by an offset,
usually expressed in hex, from the start.  So an even better
version of the stack above might be

```
libc.so`pause()+0x12
libfoo.so`c()+0x42
libfoo.so`b()+0x12
libfoo.so`a()+0x12
```

At this point, the developer can use a "disassembler" on libfoo.so
to display the instructions within c();  comparison with c()'s
source code would allow him to reveal the specific line from which
the call to pause() was made.

Before concluding this description of stacks, it's worth making
one more observation.  Given the presence of sufficient "debug
data" in a library such as libfoo, a better debugger would be able
to go the extra mile and display the the source code file name and
line number instead of the hexadecimal offset for each "frame" in
the stack.

So now, to return to the stack in your question,
libpython(2.7.so.1) is a library whose functions perform the job
of executing a Python script.  Functions in the Python script are
converted into executable instructions on the fly, so my guess is
that the fragment

```
libpython2.7.so.1`0x800b33250
libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4e2f
libpython2.7.so.1`PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x665
```

means that PyEval_EvalFrameEx() is functionality within libpython
itself that calls a Python function (i.e. something written in
Python) that resides in memory near the address 0x800b33250.  A
simple debugger can see that this address belongs to libpython but
won't find a corresponding entry in the library's symbol table;
left with no choice, it simply prints the "raw" address.

So, you need to look at the Python script so see what it's
doing but, unfortunately, there's no indication of the names of
the functions in the *Python* component of the stack.

There are a few ways to proceed.  The first is to find a
version of libpython, if one exists, with a ["DTrace helper"](https://blogs.oracle.com/levon/entry/python_and_dtrace_in_build).  This
is some extra functionality that lets DTrace see the state of the
Python program itself in addition to the surrounding
implementation.  The result is that each Python frame would be
annotated with the corresponding point in the Python source code.

Another, if you're on Solaris, is to use pstack(1);  this has
native support for Python.

Finally, try a specific Python debugger.

It's also worth pointing out that your dtrace invocation will show
you all the stacks seen, sorted by popularity, whenever the
program "python2.7" makes a system call.  From your description,
this probably isn't what you want.  If you're trying to understand
the behaviour of a hang then you probably want to start with a
single snapshot of the python2.7 process *at the time of the
hang*.

Comment: This was a great answer and I was able to use it to fully debug my problem. I previously tried the python debugger but it would just hang and not run the script, most likely because there were some multiprocessing.Processes, I also looked into DTrace but the python helpers all seemed pretty out of date; with the above answer I was able to sort it all out.