# Show the stack trace from a stuck v2 Python.exe application in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have the same question as [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/showing-the-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application) with two differences: I'm looking for answers that work on Windows 10 and Python v2.

> I have this Python application that gets stuck from time to time and I
> can't find out where.
>
> Is there any way to signal Python[.exe] to show you the exact
> code that's running?
>
> Some kind of on-the-fly stacktrace?

I run it as a `.bat` file so I can see its log, but when it locks up like this, nothing prints.

I *have* access to the source code, but I'm unfamiliar with the project at that level; ideally, I wouldn't need to edit the source code to get a stack trace, but if that's the only way, I'm willing to do it. I'm trying to gather enough information to write up a useful bug report for the maintainers.

Comment: could be wrong but to get a stack trace you have to handle exceptions that the code throws and log the exceptions

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman Evidence suggests there is no error being thrown. See the quoted text.

Comment: [py-spy](https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/) should work... have you tried it?

Comment: @DanielKaplan try using Eclipse and installing the python plugin, then you can run the code in debug mode line by line and watch it and trace to where it hangs in the code.

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman I can't consistently get it to hang.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Not sure, maybe have a script run sets of inputs to find out what inputs cause a hang, its quicker than by hand trial and error

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman  This isn't a simple algorithm. It's a code base with tens of thousands of lines and I have no idea what part of it is causing the issue.

Comment: @DanielKaplan yes so an integrated development environment really helps when learning a new code base.  Running in debug mode lets you watch the code execute line by line and you can inspect variable values on the fly, really helps.  I would ask the previous people if they are available how they did config management, maybe they already have a solution how they debug

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman I don't disagree with anything you're saying, but I don't think it's the appropriate use of my time. This isn't a project I've inherited, nor a project I'm being paid to maintain, it's an application I use and I want to file a bug report. Problem is, "It randomly hangs," isn't enough information to file a bug report.

Comment: @DanielKaplan sounds like you need a helper!

Answer (score -1):

Try to attach WinDbg from Debugging Tools for Windows to Python process or add global exception handler using traceback in the code.

Somthing similar to this:

```py
import traceback

try:
    # Your main application code here
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: This isn't ideal because, "ideally, I wouldn't need to edit the source code to get a stack trace, but if that's the only way, I'm willing to do it." More importantly, "I have this Python application that gets stuck from time to time and I can't find out where." The issue is likely an infinite loop, not a "swallowed exception."

Comment: what about you using Signal Handling with External Script?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with doing that. If it is a solution, feel free to post it as an answer. Thanks